# When should code formatting be used for non-code text?

Tags: discussion, faq, review-queues, edits, code-formatting

I reviewed an edit that did no change to the post apart from introducing code formatting `like this` to words that aren't code, such as iOS and Android (while curiously leaving Delphi untouched). I didn't really see the point of this so I rejected the edit as too minor, only to see it had already been approved.

Is there some guideline that OS names should use code formatting? To me, it seems the change does little to improve the post and shouldn't have been approved, but since several reviewers disagreed I believe I should ask it here.

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Code formatting shouldn't be used for emphasis on regular words. That includes technology names like "iOS", "GitHub", "C#", or any other proper nouns; they don't need any special formatting. As for what it *should* be used for:

Inline code formatting can be useful for:

- Micro-snippets of code (This is especially important for HTML tags or things that resemble HTML tags, since [some HTML is allowed in posts and the site will try to render anything between `<` and `>`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites))

  - `init()`
  - `if (boolean) {`
  - `<form action="..." method="post">`
  - `<strong>`
  - `<level>`
  - `&nbsp;`
- Filenames and filepaths

  - `readme.txt`
  - `.htaccess`
  - `C:\windows\system32`
  - `__init__.py`
- Shell commands, or executable names written as you'd write them at your terminal:

  - `git`
  - `cp file1.txt file2.txt`
- Showing a URL that you *don't* want to render into something clickable

  - `http://www.example.com`
- Data

  - form input values
  - text that an algorithm will operate on

---

Code **block** formatting can be useful for [errors and logs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286706), especially when:

- They're meant to be in a monospaced font

  ```
  01-25 22:13:18.594: DEBUG/skia(4204): xxxxxxxxxxx jpeg error 20 Improper call to JPEG library in state %d
  01-25 22:13:18.604: INFO/System.out(4204): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
  01-25 22:13:18.694: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(4204): 6291456-byte external allocation too large for this process.
  01-25 22:13:18.694: ERROR/(4204): VM won't let us allocate 6291456 bytes
  01-25 22:13:18.694: DEBUG/skia(4204): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx allocPixelRef failed
  ```
- They contain spacing that is lost if it isn't pre-formatted

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "x.py", line 6, in <module>
      f(a=1, b=1)
    File "x.py", line 4, in f
      return 1 / (a+1) + 1 / (b-1)
                         ~~^~~~~~~
  ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
  ```

Just make sure to disable [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work):

````
```none
your logs/errors here
```
````

(Also consider using quote blocks instead, especially for long single-line error messages.)

---

**Beyond these examples, use [other, more suitable formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).**

So for example, don't use code formatting for:

- Emphasising words.
  Use *italic* or **bold** text instead (sparingly).
- Keyboard keys.
  Use the [`<kbd>` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270967).
- Tables.
  Use proper [Markdown tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) instead

Comment: Also, you know, actual code.

Comment: The error code example is about code blocks, but everything else, including the question, appears to be discussing inline code spans.  Should that really be included in this answer (and/or should a single-line example be chosen)?

Comment: @M.Justin Already covered in the answer by "Micro-snippets of code". Let me move that item up to the top of the list, though. Also, the indentation here was apparently broken by the CommonMark migration, so I've fixed that, too.

Comment: I find it's a good way to indicate search strings without confusion about punctutation marks, e.g.: Have you tried using <your favorite search engine> to look for `wombat query vms`? Searches for `bacon levitation` and `"bacon levitation"` tend to be quite different.

Comment: The style I've settled on for writing documentation/instructions is to use monospace text to indicate UI elements or other text the user might encounter (e.g. "Click the `OK` button to close the `Preferences` dialog"), and I've carried that over to Stack Overflow/Exchange.  Care must be taken and context must be given to adequately separate it from actual code so it's not mistaken as such, but I think `monospace` makes more sense for that purpose than using "quotes" and especially **bold** or _italics_.

Comment: A couple specific ideas for Python: 1) use backticks for the name of a third-party package or tool *as it would appear in the source code*, such as in an import statement; or on a command line: "run `pip install -e .`". Use normal formatting for a package or tool as it would appear in documentation: "use Pip to install the package". 2) use backticks for the word "class" when specifically referring to the relevant code: "since `Example` was defined as a `class`, ..." / "since `Example` was defined using the `class` keyword, ..." Use plain text more generally: "since `Example` is a class, ...".

Comment: @Lance Why monospaced though? I use bold, personally. That lets me do things like give the name of a VSCode command *and* its ID clearly, like "**Tasks: Run Task** (`workbench.action.tasks.runTask`)".

Comment: @wjandrea don't suggest keyboard keys here. This answer is about code formatting, not about keyboard key formatting.

Comment: @Cerbrus I see your point, but it's specifically not about code formatting, it's about formatting non-code as if it were code. It'd be clearer if I wrote "For keyboard keys, **it's fine**, but it's better to use the `<kbd>` tag". How would you feel about that?

Comment: ... It ___is___ about `code formatting`... __Don't__ suggest things people shouldn't do. By your logic you could also add _"You can use  a code block to display a table, but you should use markdown tables, instead."_

Comment: @Cerbrus What I meant to say is, it's about code formatting, but not strictly about formatting code, you know? Anyway, I'm not saying *not* to do it, I'm saying you *can* do it, but there's a better option. What I had in mind was direction to editors, like to say "always remove code formatting used for emphasis, but if it's used for keyboard keys, you can leave it". And I would say the same exact thing for tables. For one thing, there are a lot of old posts from before we had proper tables that are still fine. Unless their text overflows, I don't bother changing them.

Comment: I'm considering filling in some details but I'm not sure everyone would agree. LMK: 1) **Why not**: It's not any clearer. The formatting is just a distraction. 2) **What to use instead**: Bold or italics can be used to add emphasis *if necessary*. In the edit OP's referring to, it's not. I see a lot of edits like this where people add code formatting to key terms (I guess), but 90% of the time, they don't need emphasis. Sometimes, BTW, terms can be confused with code, like if you write "`iterator`" in a Python question, could you be referring to `collections.abc.Iterator`?

Comment: I don't know how I can make this any simpler @wjandrea: ___Do not suggest bad practices___, especially if that's just a stepping stone to a different off-topic suggestion. `<kbd>` is irrelevant here, so don't suggest a bad practice to suggest `<kbd>`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Who's saying it's bad practice?

Comment: @wjandrea This post is about code formatting, so it should not contain any suggestions about formatting things that are not code.

Comment: @TylerH I agree with `wjandrea` that the mall-formatted code span instead of `<kdb>` is a common enough problem. A compromise solution is including a link to a relevant post at the end of this canonical that explains its use. After editing hundreds if not thousands of such cases I have to agree it warrants a reference.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, what? This question is about formatting *non-code* as code and this answer includes filenames and URLs.

Comment: @wjandrea Headers or emphasis are not code or code-adjacent, so are irrelevant to this post and thus should not be included.

Comment: This answer is not about fromatting non-code as something other than code, so that _shouldn't_ be added in here.

Comment: @TylerH Who's talking about headers? Regarding emphasis, the answer explicitly recommends against it. I'm sorry, I'm not following you at all.

Comment: @bad_coder Done. I added a section about other cases where code formatting ideally shouldn't be used on non-code. No link though cause I couldn't find anything specific enough from a quick look.

Comment: @wjandrea You were, it seemed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995?noredirect=1#comment983247_254995 But maybe your comment was not very clear.

Comment: @TylerH oh, I thought you were replying to [my other comment](/q/254990/#comment983246_254995). I'm still not following you though, and I'm not sure what made you think of headers.

Comment: Dude. If you add a recommendation and then immediately invalidate that recommendation, you ___shouldn't add that recommendation___. Especially not if the better alternative is ___off-topic___.

Comment: @Cerbrus No offense, but did you read the edit you just rolled back? It basically said "also, don't do this ...".

Comment: You're just shoehorning those examples in there. The only reason that mentions _tables_ is because ___I___ brought them up as an extremely bad example. I've hardly _ever_ seen people use code blocks for tables on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, you just spammed the comment section 6 times making the same argument - we heard you already. I'm of the same opinion as wjandrea, the linked examples (especially the kbd) advert the most common mistakes and deserve mention.

Comment: @Cerbrus Here are some examples I found from a quick look: [Bash parameter expansions](//stackoverflow.com/a/16753536), [Python operator precedence](//stackoverflow.com/a/74231772), [git command timetables](//stackoverflow.com/a/42165259). And here's [a Meta question from before 2020](/q/302471) where the answer has a table formatted as code, which suggests there are a lot more out there.

Comment: @Cerbrus Also, bad_coder doesn't represent me. I still respect you even if I totally disagree with you, so the fact that you think my points are basically "No you're wrong" is really disappointing.

Comment: @wjandrea those are _old_ examples, examples that show _command output_, not tables, and that Meta question with the _"table formatted as code"_ is __explaining how markdown tables work__. None of them are examples of people using code blocks to render tabled. If anything, that meta question invalidates the need to mention tables here.

Comment: @wjandrea your argument can be summarized to _"I'm not saying not to do it, I'm saying you can do it, but there's a better option."_ That just flips my argument. I'm stating you ___shouldn't___. Your answer is _"you can"_... That's not a good answer / justification.

Comment: You could also wrap them in emojis, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, I changed my position, was that not clear? I'm now saying "Don't do it, but if you see it, you don't need to bother fixing it." (Whereas for emphasis, it should always be fixed.)

Comment: @Cerbrus *"those are old examples"* - One of them's from 2022, but regardless, why does their age matter? Like I said, I'm thinking of direction to editors, including about old posts. *"examples that show command output"* - The first two are not, or if they are, IDK what commands they would be from. *"If anything, that meta question invalidates the need to mention tables here."* - In what way? If editors are looking for guidance about code formatting, how is that going to lead them to a question about tables?

Comment: The one from 2022 isn't even a table... And even if it was, That's ___one___ example. You're using that meta question as an example of a table in a code block. Implying that it should've been formatted as a table, instead. That code block is ___Markdown syntax___ for a table. That has ___nothing___ to do with this question.

Comment: But we're not getting anywhere with this back and forth. Let's end this.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"The one from 2022 isn't even a table"* - Oh yeah, I should have clarified, it's an *attempt* at a table, but it's misaligned. *"That code block is Markdown syntax for a table."* - Oh, you didn't read the whole thing! Look under "Pre-November 2020".

Comment: I've tweaked this post a bit, including adding a section about common abuses of code formatting to avoid. I've primarily done this because I want a source I can cite when rejecting the endless stream of suggested edits that use backticks for emphasis or stick them around technology-related proper nouns like `iPhone` and `C#`; prior to the edit, the answer didn't definitively say that using backticks for such words is wrong. @Cerbrus, given the distaste you've voiced for showing examples of the wrong formatting, I've taken care to only gives *examples* of *correct* formatting in those cases.

Comment: This is a FAQ entry. It should be simple to read and to the point. It should not be bloated with all kinds of examples of what not to do. As I stated more than once already in the comments here, the large notice at the bottom of the post now _more than_ covers the "other" formatting cases.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't agree. It's not clear if that large notice is meant to mean that *literally any other use of backticks* is inappropriate, and either way is problematic. If it *does* mean that, it's wrong, since other accepted uses exist (one of which you just edited out!). If it *doesn't*, this post simply doesn't answer whether backticking technology and language names is appropriate, despite having been used as a dupe target multiple times for that precise question. Yes, it's an FAQ entry, and for that reason it should exhaustively cover at least the things that are frequently asked about!

Comment: Like, literally what's the point of having an FAQ entry for this and using it as a dupe target if we're just gonna provide a partial answer, shrug and decide it's long enough, and roll back attempts to make it more exhaustive? It'd literally be more useful for this entire Q&A to *not exist* if we approach it like that, since at least then it wouldn't be used as a basis for closing other questions! We need to be able to document the answers to recurring policy questions *somewhere*.

Comment: We shouldn't be duplicating information out of the help center. FAQ exists to fill the gaps. And an even more serious reason I reverted those edit is that they state _tables_ are okay to use code blocks for. That's _blatantly_ incorrect. The whole reason _tables_ were added, is because wjandrea misinterpreted [a comment from me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995#comment983225_254995) explaining tables should ___never___ be code blocks.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'd appreciate it if you were to @-notify me when rolling back my edits or making changes I'm likely to disagree with; I've done you that courtesy!

Comment: @Cerbrus *"an even more serious reason I reverted those edit is that they state tables are okay to use code blocks for"* - huh? They explicitly said it's better to use proper Markdown tables, and to edit old posts that used code blocks for tables to convert them to use proper tables instead. I double-checked the edit history to see if I made some terrible typo, but no, the edits you reverted definitely said the exact opposite of what you're saying they said. I can make the instruction *not* to use code blocks for this even more clear if you think it's somehow open to misinterpretation...

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. Still, I'm not interested in repeating this entire discussion in these comments ___again___, @MarkAmery, these FAQ entries shouldn't list every single thing you _shouldn't_ do. That footer already more than covers that. The more extensive you make that list, the more you give people to point out edge-cases not covered by that list. _"But it doesn't say I can't use code formatting for city names!"_

Comment: @Cerbrus If the FAQ doesn't indicate whether common abuses of code formatting are right or wrong, it simply doesn't provide a useful answer to the question asked. Even the original question body asked specifically about the constantly recurring topic of whether words like `iOS` should be backticked - the very thing you insist we shouldn't answer! Again, if all we're gonna do is provide a non-exhaustive list of fairly obviously okay uses of backticks and leave it at that, what's the *point* of this FAQ?

Comment: @Cerbrus *"That footer already more than covers that"* - how? I don't think that footer really has much meaning at all, and don't understand what purpose you think it serves. *Possibly* you take it to convey that all uses of code formatting besides those listed in the answer are inappropriate... but it doesn't clearly say that, and it *shouldn't*, since that's untrue and contradicts the bit earlier in the post about the list of places to use code formatting not being definitive. It's in effect not saying much more than "Some other kinds of formatting exist, and here are some docs about them".

Comment: _"iOS"_ is not a code snippet, filename, or URL, so shouldn't be code. How does this not answer that @MarkAmery? The link points to other options for formatting... For other cases where `code` formatting clearly isn't okay, as it's not a code snippet, filename, or URL. You're looking way too much into this. IT's an extremely simple list fo 3 items for inline code, and 2 for code blocks. Other than that, don't use code formatting. Don't overcomplicate this.

Comment: *""iOS" is not a code snippet, filename, or URL, so shouldn't be code. How does this not answer that @MarkAmery?"* - because the bulleted list that includes code snippets, filenames, and URLs is not an exhaustive list of *all* the things it's appropriate to use code formatting for, and even has a disclaimer above it (that indeed you keep restoring!) explicitly noting that it's not a definitive list! We're directly saying before we even get into the list that there is additional stuff it's appropriate to use code formatting for that we haven't listed.

Comment: There, fixed it, @MarkAmery. Those 3 top categories _are_ and always have been well-defined.

Comment: @Cerbrus But it's not a fix, because it's genuinely *not* an exhaustive list! As just one example, names of shell commands like `git` or `cp` are commonly backticked and that's fine and correct, but they don't appear in the old list (and you've twice reverted my attempts to add that common use case to the list...) On the one hand you don't want to make the list actually be exhaustive, but on the other you want people to reason that backticks are inappropriate in some scenarios because those scenarios aren't on the (non-exhaustive) list; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: shell is code. @MarkAmery, if you'd edit a shell command example, by itself, into those list, I'd be ___absolutely okay___ with that. I'm ___fine___ with listing _okay_ examples of code blocks / inline code. Just don't list bad uses.

Comment: Those 3 categories _are_ exhaustive. Unless you can think of another one. The lists under them are just examples. Actually, 4 categories now, but IMO, shell commands are just code. Not a hill to die on though.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am sure there are several more. Off the top of my head: 1. Indicating something to be typed verbatim (but which is nonetheless not exactly code), like a default username or password. 2. Indicating that a series of characters represents string data that an algorithm will operate on (but perhaps not as *code* per se - such data might not be written as a string literal with quotes, especially in a language-agnostic algorithm question). I've seen code formatting used for both of these and consider it appropriate for both.

Comment: _Data_ is a fine example to add under code. Sample form inputs, (verbatim data), just as well... Or just add a category _"Test / example data"_. Again, I'm absolutely fine with listing __proper uses__. @MarkAmery (I keep forgetting the mention)

Comment: Just... Please don't edit the tables example back into it. It's been used as a hack in the past, and it was only ever added into this answer because that other user completely misinterpreted my comment.

Comment: Personally, I think adding my two data examples in would be too pedantic; we don't need to list every unusual use case of code formatting that the community has ever decided it's okay with. It makes much more sense to me to *explicitly* highlight common *misuses* of code formatting and say not to do them - it was after all the *misuses* that this very question was originally about!

Comment: @MarkAmery how is this, is that an okay compromise?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes - actually very similar to something I already had in my editor. I'm gonna hit save, but feel free to take a look and decide what to keep from each version. I'd be able to live with yours if you entirely prefer it!

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look @MarkAmery.

Comment: @Cerbrus I see your latest edit - looks good to me. I think we've grumpily haggled our way into producing something significantly better than what *either* of us originally wanted, so, thank you! (I am still not a big fan of the giant heading but I can live with it and many of the other changes you've either made or nudged me into along the way are big improvements on my first draft from earlier today.)

Comment: Let's grumpily shake hands on a job well done, then @MarkAmery. The header was quite important to me, as that's a big signpost stating _"Hey, we have formatting documentation"_ :D

Comment: @TylerH Why'd you rollback?

Comment: @wjandrea While a CW, the post above is not necessarily a place for users to place their personal preferences. There's no issue with using block quotes, for example, with error messages (in fact it is the ideal format). That users make mistakes is not a process issue. I also don't see a need to point out that markdown table support was added in 2020. All edits are made in present time no matter what time (or year) that is; no one is making an edit in 2017 based on this guidance.

Comment: @TylerH *"That users make mistakes is not a process issue."* - True, but it's an easy mistake to make, for example if you have a word in angle brackets, it'll go missing and you might not notice from a quick glance. While for inline code formatting, the only special characters you need to worry about are backticks, which affect the result in an obvious way.

Comment: @TylerH *"no one is making an edit in 2017 based on this guidance"* - Well yeah, but there are posts from 2017 out there that still have tables formatted as code. The reason I mentioned it is so that editors are aware of it and don't feel obliged to reformat old tables, I mean, as long as they're perfectly readable of course.

Comment: @TylerH BTW, this is relevant: [Add format for logs/warnings/error messages which allows word-wrapping and preserves newlines - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235084/343832)

Comment: @TylerH On second thought, I'm going to drop the blockquote/inline debate. Code block is the better option overall IMHO, and this answer recommends it first, so w/e. I would only use inline as a last resort.

Answer (score 60):

Code formatting should never be used for non-code text, except in very limited circumstances such as filenames, URLs, etc.

The use of backticks to `emphasise` individual `words` is especially `pernicious`.

Any suggested edit that adds such formatting should be rejected.

If you see any posts that use it edit it out along with fixing as many of the other problems with the post as you can.

Comment: "such formatting should be rejected", we could **rather improve the edit** using bold to emphasize and italic for _special terms or titles_, the HTML-kbd tag for shortcuts like `<kbd>Shift</kbd>`.