# Should this edit that put code formatting around controls and languages have been approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, code-formatting

When I was reviewing suggested edits lately, I come across a user who put `code formatting` around every `language` and `control` that is mentioned in a post. They also added white-spaces after lots of the sentences. I had always thought that `languages` and `generic control names` (such as `buttons`) shouldn't have `code formatting` around them (because for one thing, the post gets very messy), so I rejected the edits. However, three other users [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5121606) them.

I read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text), and it seems like code languages and generic control names shouldn't have code formatting.

So should the above edit have been rejected?
 Or was this proper use of formatting?

Comment: @rene, I rephrased my question to be more clear about what I was asking.

Comment: I saw that and still feel the answers on the dup qualify as answers here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Language names (like PHP, C#, HTML, CSS, JavaScript) are almost never candidates for code formatting, because they are proper nouns, just like Alice and Bob and Stack Overflow.

Generic control names that are simply part of natural language sentences should not be code-formatted either. Only when it's the name of an identifier in code should it be code-formatted, for example a `Button` class or a `TextBox` class.

That edit should not have been approved. The *only* part of the post where inline code formatting was appropriate was `$(document).ready`, but since it's an extremely minor edit and certainly one the post could live without, the editor should have just refrained from editing the post altogether.