# Go programming language syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

From the [go tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) for the Go programming language:

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): default

Why doesn't it specify `lang-go`?

> [are you sure that you've got the correct highlighting turned on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/221700)
>
> Behind the scenes, Stack Exchanges uses the tags on the question to
>   infer the language you are using.
>   ... 
>   If you're curious whether a tag has a language hint, any user is
>   capable of checking by visiting that tag's wiki page. The language
>   hint (if any) that is currently being used for that tag will be
>   displayed at the very bottom, below the buttons for the wiki.

References:

[The Go Programming Language](http://golang.org/)

[What is syntax highlighting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/221700)

[Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)

[lang-go.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-go.js)

Answer (score 4):

This got added to the list at some point so it is now set for the [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) tag. Let me know if it causes any problems, but a quick look at the tag suggests it will help far more questions than it will hinder.