# Go programming language syntax highlighting broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Go programming language syntax highlighting should work, it was implemented some time ago, see related question:

[Go programming language syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274542/go-programming-language-syntax-highlighting)

However, without explicitly specifying the language using `<!-- language: lang-golang -->`, syntax highlighting does not work for Go. It worked in the past, but now it doesn't work, neither for new nor for old (existing) questions.

Using the [expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) language indicator for Go `<!-- language: lang-go -->` it doesn't work also. When using `<!-- language: lang-golang -->` it works.

As Gimby suggests, the [Go tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) displays:

```
Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-go
```

Most likely the code language has been changed / renamed without taking care of updating all reference / usage of it.

Comment: According to the link, it should be `<-- language: lang-go -->`.

Comment: @Gimby Actually when using `<-- language: lang-go -->` it doesn't work either. When using `<-- language: lang-golang -->`, it works.

Comment: Well there apparently lies the disconnect, the bottom of the go tag states: *Code Language: lang-go* . Apparently the identifier for the go language got changed and the tag wasn't updated to match.

Comment: @Gimby And who can edit that?

Comment: Only stack employees I think. Just have to be patient until this bug report is seen / picked up.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks. Included your suggestion / finding in the answer.

Comment: @Gimby mods have the ability too.

Comment: @Braiam So mods _can_ edit it, but _will_ they edit it? I assume this is a 1-minute edit task. I also think the question got enough attention (41 upvotes), how to make this happen?

Comment: @icza I was actually wondering the same thing since this [tag dupe problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332027/processingjs-processing-js) got resolved in an instant. I am thinking the tagging is wrong; this is a data problem and not a software bug. Perhaps it should be re-tagged as a feature request

Comment: The struggle of waiting four days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with the next build, the syntax highlighter config dropdown will say "lang-golang".

Comment: And when is this next build scheduled, or did it happen already? Because syntax highlighting for Go still doesn't work. Or if this needs to be selected manually on the [Go tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) page, can someone do it?

Comment: @icza Yeah, it needed to be picked on the tag page. I did that now.

Answer (score 6):

So I just tried to do this. Here's the problem:

> [image]

Manually editing the HTML  on the page to inject a `lang-golang` one doesn't seem to work for whatever reason. We'll need a developer or CM to add `lang-golang` to the whitelist for default highlighting languages.