# processingjs == processing.js

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I'll just cut to the chase: The [processingjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processingjs) tag should be deleted, and the 3 questions in it should be retagged with the [processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing.js) tag.

I can just manually edit the tags to remove them, but then will the empty [processingjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processingjs) tag still be around, tempting people to use it?

Is there some extra process I should start to get the [processingjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processingjs) tag completely removed rather than just emptying it out? Or is emptying it out enough?

**Edit:** I've edited the questions to retag them with the [processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing.js) tag. Is that enough?

Comment: If a tag doesn't have any questions with it, it is automatically purged from the system. I don't remember exactly when but the script runs daily at 2 or 3 AM UTC (or something like that). So emptying it out is enough.

Comment: @Tunaki Oh okay cool. I've retagged all of the questions with the [tag:processing.js] tag.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if there is some implicit coercion going on in that title ;).

Comment: Someone could add it as a tag synonym

Comment: Hmmmm... `==` is equal but not ness the same type. Did you mean to use `===`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've merged between the tags, adding a synonym from [processingjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processingjs) to [processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing.js).