# Syntax highlighting has a slight bug for swift function labels

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019963/296446):

The 2nd `#` marks the label as required and should not be treated as a comment.

Code:

```
func addLocation(#latitude : Double, #longitude : Double) { /*...*/ }
addLocation(latitude: 125.0, longitude: -34.1) // Better
```

Image of rendering on Stack Overflow:

[image]

The response to a [Prettify support request](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/439) claims that this is on Stack Overflow's end, not theirs.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the default highlighting scheme, as there is no dedicated language hint for Swift. Someone should get around to implementing one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)