# Should I add a programming language tag to questions about frameworks?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a lot of question about frameworks, which aren't tagged with the used programming language. Frequent examples are questions about WPF. Sometimes the questions are not related to the used language and I understand, that they are not tagged with it. But if a question has some related code, there is often no tag for the programming language.

Should a question about a framework always be tagged with the used
programming language if the language is related to the question? Should this also be done if it's clear which language is used?

**Advantages**: More people will find the question if they set their filter to a programming language and can answer questions about the framework as well.

**Disadvantages**: A lot of people which want to find questions on a programming language will find the framework-related questions as well, but they might not want to find them.

Comment: A WPF question that is just around a XAML issue doesn't necessarily need the C# tag, so no, it shouldn't always be tagged with one.

Comment: @Joe I mentioned this in my question. For clarity I will update my answer

Comment: Should, for example, [tag:jQuery] questions then also be tagged with [tag:javascript]? What happens if the user manually added 5 tags already? And what if the user entered 4 tags, but 2 of them could have language tags added?

Comment: If there is space for a language-tag, it is obvious which one should be used, and there is no good reason to leave it out, just add it. Which means nearly all questions will get a language-tag, and the automatic syntax-highlighting depending on it. (Manual hinting is comparably clumsier.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I would always tag it with the appropriate language tag. Even in your example with WPF, I frequently have to include C# snippets to explain my answer, which obviously aren't useful if you *actually* needed VB. More is more in this case.

Also, as you noted more people follow C# than WPF, so you'll get more eyes on your question. If somebody just *hates* WPF questions, they can always ignore the tag.

Comment: I would also imagine that some of those tags don't have syntax highlighting, but the language tags take care of that.

Comment: > If somebody just hates WPF questions, they can always ignore the tag.

This scenario happens often with Dart and Flutter, but the situation is not so simple. Even if I exclude questions with the `flutter` tag, many people leave it out, instead adding only a topic specific tag like `flutter-layout`. As a result, it's practically impossible to filter for Dart-only questions.

Answer (score 3):

One good reason to add the a language tag is to force the implied syntax highlighting to trigger which directly improves readability.

---

Consider this piece from [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/691711):

> Tags:
>
> You can specify any tag that exists on the site, and it will use
>   whatever language code is currently specified for that tag. Keep in
>   mind that by default all tags start off with none as their language
>   code. Tags with none specified as their language code will be ignored
>   and revert to default.
>
> You can also use the plain none keyword to manually specify no syntax
>   highlighting, similar to using the lang-none code above.

If you don't tag with something that is in the [list of supported languages](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md#for-which-languages-does-it-work), nothing gets highlighted.

For example, if you tag a question with only "angular", no syntax highlighting is applied even though the post would benefit from JavaScript/TypeScript highlighting.

I guess alternatively you could go through and manually add the `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->` annotation or maybe ask to have the framework's tag associated to a specific syntax highlighting rule, but I think the question still benefits from the language tag.

Comment: But you can use markdown language hints to choose the programming language: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting