# Is it OK to use language-specific tags for problems with that are not directly connected to coding in such language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Let say, I have a problem installing / updating / integrating a framework for a specific popular programming language.  The problem is related to the language, since those that do not use it wouldn't likely to ever face such problem, but in essence has nothing to do with *programming* in the said language.

The framework has its own tag, but it's popularity is just a fraction of the general language tag's.

Is it acceptable to plug in a popular tag in order to expose my question to a wider audience or would it irritate those who monitor this tag looking for strictly programming problems?

Comment: Other related questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289201, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250876, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167866/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133140

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344085/, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341876, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316708, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302863, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293878, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276056, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308179, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357202, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342436

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that is usually a good thing. Tags exist for searching and filtering. Questions should include tags that are **directly relevant to the topic** at hand (in this case, the framework's tag), and *secondarily* should also include tags that are indirectly relevant.

For example, I often see questions about JavaScript about applying styles. The questions typically have the JavaScript tag (okay, that one's obvious), but they also have the CSS tag. Sometimes this is a good thing, in the cases where they're trying to do something with JavaScript that might be easier done with CSS, or if the problem is that they're using the wrong style in their JavaScript code.

Similarly, people who ask jQuery questions tend to tag their questions as JavaScript. This is good because sometimes there are things that are done more efficiently in vanilla JavaScript (or, again, CSS) instead of jQuery (like if someone is introducing the jQuery library just for a single interaction).

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of stuff going on in the language tags already, I don't think anyone expects these tags to be applied *only* to purely language-related questions.

If you're talking about a popular framework for the language, I'd say it's perfectly fine to include the language tag for visibility. After all, the language is relevant as people familiar with the language may know the framework without actually following its dedicated tag.

There are other situations where you shouldn't do it. I'm mostly thinking of questions like *"How do I parse JavaScript in C#"* (let's put the question quality aside for a moment here, it's just an example off the top of my head) - this one shouldn't be tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), it should have the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag though. This helps both with relevance and choosing the best language for syntax highlighting.

Comment: In JavaScript situation it would be something like "*having problem with installing `AngularJS` plug-in in `Eclipse`*".

Comment: We have to do the best that is given to us with existing tools. There is no distinction between tags about languages and code in specific tags. Frankly, this is good, because the distinction would make tagging a usability nightmare. I would always include both language tags for questions like *How do I parse JavaScript in C#* (but it's probably too broad), because both language tags are very relevant.

Answer (score -2):

Trying to summarize from related question I linked to from comments.

From the point of view of the asker:

- Pro: Higher chance of question being read by hitting answerers favorite tags, in particular for niche frameworks/libraries. In fact, omitting niche tags that many people filter out can further increase visibility
- Pro: More tag-related badge-score gain on every upvote
- Pro: language tag improves heuristic for syntax highlighting
- Con: Framework/library experts using a different language may filter out question

From the point of view of eager answerers:

- Pro: Hiding specific languages best works if questions have the language tag
- Pro: More tag-related badge-score gain on every upvote
- Pro: favorite tag based highlighting show question even when answerer did not add framework to his favorites, question gets his attention
- Con: When following a language tag, being spammed by questions on specific frameworks / libraries (but could be filtered out)
- Con: not clear at a glance whether language knowledge alone could be sufficient
- Con: more competition from general language experts to niche-framework experts, when hunting for reputation

From the point of view of other readers:

- Pro: Better statistics about language use
- Pro: More context about any post does not hurt, helps indexing, searching

Overall it seems adding a language tag commonly has more benefits than drawbacks, so a language tag that is superflous is the lesser of 2 evils in an imperfect world.