# What about a global "pure"-tag which is combinable with all programming-language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of programming-languages which often aren't used in their native form. They are used together with plugins, modifications, frameworks.
To find questions you can possibly answer it is easy to filter by a plugins name - but it is impossible to filter for questions which are based on the original programming language.

**for example:** I can easily filter for the PHP framework "Yii" and will find a lot of questions regarding Yii.
But if I want to look for "pure" or "native" PHP questions, I can only filter for "PHP". The result will then contain "pure" PHP questions but also a lot of questions regarding PHP frameworks which I am not interested in when I am only used to "pure" PHP.

In my humble opinion there should be something like a "pure" tag - which is combinable with every programming language to make it easier to find questions about the original language only.

Comment: You can filter on `[php]` and *ignore* tags that don't interest you; see your preferences in your profile. You are never going to get question askers to keep adding the `[pure]` tag, anyway.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work); votes denote agreement here. People that downvote feel that such a tag would not be useful or would work.

Comment: Those 7 downvotes don't imply this question is unconstructive. They're expressing disagreement to the request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this would be a workaround which includes a lot of work for each user. if there are new plugins for a language you always would have to add them too. it would be so useful and much more simple if you could just filter for `[php#pure]` for example.

Comment: So, what if a question is tagged `[php],[html],[javascript]`?

Comment: @low_rents: there is *no need* for such a tag. It is pure noise. The site already lets you filter out tags you are not interested in. Learn to use those instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I strongly disagree. there are hundreds or even thousands of plugins for some programming languages. it's not user-friendly to let them filter out each one of them for each programming-language they are interested in. and everyone would have to agree that filtering for something like `[java#pure]`, `[php#pure]`, etc. would be much better if you are just interested in such questions.

Comment: @low_rents: where are there hundreds or even thousands of tags denoting individual 'plugins' (libraries, frameworks, etc.)? You are inventing problems here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you want to, you can add the "pure-modifier" to some, all or none of them, e.g. `[php#pure], [html], [javascript#pure]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters just think about `node.js` or `javascript`. I am sure there is more than a thousand for each of them already.

Comment: How this suggestion is different from using existing `functional-programming` tag?

Comment: @low-rents instead of 'i am sure' giving actual numbers would help

Comment: @MartijnPieters For example, since JavaScript is used so much nowadays, if I only want _pure_ JS, I would have to ignore hundreds of tags

Answer (score 8):

A "Pure" tag would be a typical meta-tag.

Meta tags should be avoided:

> ## Avoid meta-tags
>
> Do not use meta-tags in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`, and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question.
> - **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** For example, the meaning of the tag `[subjective]` is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like `[best-practices]` and `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition.

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging))

Comment: then just don't let it be a meta-tag. make it a tag that automatically combines with the programming-language, for example [php-pure] or [javascript-pure]. it would just be a meta-tag if you would add it without additional logic.

Comment: @low_rents: There is no existing functionality that "automatically combines tags". I'm pretty sure that won't be implemented for this, either.

Comment: well this is a feature request - how about adding something really useful like that?

Comment: Please provide a _good_ example why this would be ___really___ useful, then. Significant changes like this require a _very_ good reason even to be considered.

Comment: the good example is: _i am a native XXX-developer and I am only interested in native XXX questions. that's why I want to filter for them_

Comment: @low_rents: So you only ever work in the language, never connecting with anything. You never parse a file, or print to the console, load data from a network connection? Everybody will have a different definition of what 'pure' means. Purity is subjective.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's depending on the language of course. sure there are different definitions, but it's quite self-explaining for people working with the language. it's the same problem with tags that already exist - for example: `[php-7], [php-7.1]`. people are using those tags even when the problem refers to other versions as well.

Comment: @low_rents: I work with several different languages. It is **not** quite self-explanatory. You are oversimplifying.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, but what is the reason we can have something like a `[php-7]` tag, and on the other hand a `[php#pure]` tag would be bad in your  opinion?

Comment: @low_rents: version-specific tags that help narrow the focus of a question (so you don't get answers requiring a different version) are a completely different thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, because I also don't want to get answers requiring a different framework than the native one with my "pure-tag" suggestion.