# JavaScript tag as a language, pure JavaScript, and all its libraries

Tags: discussion, tags

When I (a simple programmer) search for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions, I expect to find questions related to JavaScript, as a language. What I get instead is all kinds of JavaScript libraries/frameworks/whatever you want to call it questions together because people mark, for example "[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)" intead of just "[jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)" which is understandable since there's certain programmers that know all or a big chunk of those libraries/frameworks.

The issue is for people like me, who only use "pure JavaScript" have to make something like this:

[image: Ignored Tags]

What I propose is the creation of a [pure-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pure-javascript) tag and that people who use it, would still also use the normal [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag as a whole. That way it would work for both sides.

Comment: Ummm... ruby-o-rails?

Comment: The whole *pure JavaScript* idea is absurd, imho. The reason so many libraries exist for JS, is because the standard library is incredibly limited. Other (popular) languages have an expansive standard library, so there's no need to depend on third party libraries so much.

Comment: Related: [Tagging swift ObjC for framework language agnostic related questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321129) | [Congratulations Eric Lippert for finally winning the \[c#-language\] badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62669)

Comment: Related to [What about a global “pure”-tag which is combinable with all programming-language tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341876/what-about-a-global-pure-tag-which-is-combinable-with-all-programming-language/341877#341877). Not an exact dupe, but close enough, I think.

Comment: @Stijn, "the standard library is incredibly limited". JavaScript alone can do everything the JS frameworks and libraries can so what's your point?

Comment: You may have misunderstood what Stijn want to say. what most js libraries does is actually _abstracting_ some works so that a js dev doesn't have to re-invent the wheel. Still, the `pure-javascript` tag already exist, as `javascript`. It's not possible to use eg angular tag without a javascript tag because some solutions to a problem could be done with js only. So, IMO there is no point for a new "pure" tag. Using `javascript` tag is sufficient enough for me.

Comment: but... jquery IS javascript!

Comment: I know that @KevinB.

Comment: It may be good idea to show some examples of true "pure JavaScript" questions that are recent, practical and not duplicates of existing questions. That way true value of tag would be apparent. Note that you need to exclude all questions related to scripts in browsers, node.js, scripting for games, Windows shell scripting and the like.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

You'd be doubling SO's list of tags this way, and there's no support for "tag dependencies" like that, especially if you need to create a new tag for a new library.

Besides, there are plenty of questions tagged with a library that don't mind a "native" answer.