# Should I tag my Node.js questions as [javascript]?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I've asked a few [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) questions in the past couple months and I have always been adding the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, since that's the language.

One thing I noticed is SO ends up indicating the primary tag as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) since that is the more popular of the two, although really I view Node.js as sort of a separate thing. However, my view on that may be incorrect. I don't have a lot of experience in the field, my only serious exposure to JavaScript is through Node.js, I don't do a lot of web front-end development.

Should I be tagging these questions as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or not? Do Node questions annoy the JS folks? Does leaving out the tag kill the visibility? How do you guys feel about it?

Comment: I'm not an expert of it, but I wouldn't add the Javascript tag.

Comment: If you add a tag because it has another tag...

Comment: I dunno I feel the same ambiguity here as I do with [tag:java] and [tag:processing].

Comment: I'd imagine it has to do with whether the question is about node specifically, or javascript you happen to be executing with node.  Personally I'm more irked by generic JS questions that tag with node than the other way around.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Language tags are a really good way to get your question noticed. Lots of people *only* watch the language tags. So it is generally a good idea to include a language tag.

That said, by adding the JavaScript tag, you're opening up the question to a larger audience that may or may not have any experience with Node.js and its quirks. This does not make it any less likely that an expert in Node.js will see your question, but more likely that users inexperienced in Node.js will see your question.

Take from that what you will, but I would say you're safe either way.

Comment: I'm starting to get curious about this is as the Node developer community is growing stronger, is Node actually Javascript I know they say they are and are built from a Javascript Engine, but to me it seems closer to ActionScript that What is known as Javascript (DOM) it's starting to become a bit like Hot Tub/Jaccusi Javascript is ECMA script but not all ECMA script is Javascript. (P.S sorry for resurrection i just wanted some others views on this and this was too close for me to open my own question)

Comment: @MartinBarker Node is most definitely JavaScript. DOM is a library that comes bundled with browsers and is defined by the w3c. JavaScript is the implementation of the ECMAScript language specification.

Comment: ok so if Javascript is the implementation so what would you say ActionScript and JScript.Net are, are they both Javascript? I'm just curious as things have changed a lot since I started web development 15 years ago and keeping up is all good and well but stuff like this is whats confusing as I would say Node is more like ActionScript.

Comment: @MartinBarker ActionScript and JScript are both implementations of the ECMAScript language specification, Node literally uses the JavaScriipt engine from chrome to execute the JavaScript code. There are libraries that come standard with node that dont come with plain old JavaScript, but its still JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I use X tag because I have Y tag?

The answer to that question is that you are asking the wrong one. The presence or absence of any tag shouldn't impact the presence or absence or any other tag. The tags describe what the question is about, and you can't do that without looking at the body of the question. In the same way that not all jquery question need the javascript tag, not all node.js questions need javascript experts. If your question is about node.js, tag it as [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), if your question is about javascript, use the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag. If your question is about both, use both tags.

Remember "[t]ags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories." When you tag a question, you are asking the experts of that tag to take a look at it, and there isn't a more annoying thing for an expert to be called where he's not needed.

Comment: That makes sense, too, although for me with limited non-Node experience it is sometimes hard to tell where the line is between the two.

Comment: @JasonC normally, leave that to the expert on the tag. They will know exactly what knowledge is necessary to answer the question, or which isn't. It could be that your question has nothing to do with node and was a pure js question. Node answerers will notice this and replace node with js.