# Should JavaScript library questions have the JavaScript tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Before I get to the gist of the question, here are some short statistics:

- Questions tagged with [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [110,394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs%20javascript?mode=all)
- Questions tagged with [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) and without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [132,035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs%20not%20javascript?mode=all)
- Questions tagged with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [27,807](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs%20javascript?mode=all)
- Questions tagged with [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [30,967](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs%20not%20javascript?mode=all)
- Questions tagged with [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [4,754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js%20javascript?mode=all)
- Questions tagged with [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [5,147](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js%20not%20javascript?mode=all)

It seems there isn't any consensus, nor any consistency, in the way the language tag is used with library tags, regardless of library tag popularity or age.

Oftentimes, it's very clear whether a question is only about the library or only about using the language, but what about the rest of it? What should/would the preferred approach be, if it exists at all?

Comment: maybe, maybe not. depends on the question

Comment: Has anyone seen people deliberately removing [tag:javascript] from those? It sounds more likely that some people simply forget to include it.

Comment: including it brings in a much larger audience which could be a good thing, but it could also be unwanted. the last thing i'd want is people reading this and then running to add his tag to questions that don't really benefit from it other than through exposure.

Comment: Very related, possibly a duplicate, albeit with a slightly narrowed scope: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342436/should-i-tag-my-node-js-questions-as-javascript

Comment: If the library is popular enough then it doesn't need the help from a [language] tag anymore.  Do keep in mind that you are looking at historical data, every library was once not yet popular enough.  In general, anybody that looks at [javascript] question has a very low expectation that the question is actually about the language.  So it is not a real problem.

Comment: @Hans In general, if I see a question with the [javascript] tag I am going to assume that it is about JavaScript the language. If it also contains a framework tag that either means that the person is also using the framework and that tag may be irrelevant, or it may not be about JavaScript the language at all, but rather about the framework itself. I agree though that it doesn't really matter. You're more likely to get eyes on your question if you include the language tag, but you're also more likely to get eyes that don't know what you're talking about if it is a framework specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really seem to be a problem. There doesn't have to be consistency. Included or not is fine, it is obvious that JavaScript libraries are in JavaScript.

Perhaps by including multiple tags, the OP is indicating they wouldn't mind an appropriate vanilla JavaScript answer as well. Or perhaps there is a mix of both library and vanilla.

Time is best spent elsewhere.

Comment: I agree that time is best spent elsewhere. It would be a massive waste of time, and a huge disruption, if the community were to pursue retagging all of these questions. On the other hand, I don't see the harm in coming to a consensus about what should be done *moving forward*, and then experts answering these questions can retag as part of their normal edits to improve new questions.

Comment: @CodyGray - The net is cast far too wide here. There is no bandaid to fix every eventuality of language in addition to framework; not with JavaScript, not with other languages. There can be no consensus. This is probably the reason that this post has only garnered negative votes. The tag is too active, maybe in something smaller.

Answer (score -4):

Well, I don't care that much about AngularJS, since that framework is dying. With regard to Angular, there are 64K questions tagged [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), compared to 14K with both. Could that be because people are using [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)? Nope: there are 57K question about [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) without [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), compared to 16K with.

We can interpret this optimistically as meaning that people working in Angular are smarter about the distinctions between the framework and the language and are tagging more carefully to call out only the framework.

Or, we can interpret this pessimistically as meaning that even more people working in Angular don't even understand that the issues they are facing are basic JavaScript or TypeScript issues and have nothing to do with Angular, yet they tag their questions [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and leave off the language tag altogether.

Unfortunately, my experience with a number of questions indicates that the latter is more common.

To answer your specific question, if a question is about Angular routing or templating or what have you, no, I don't think a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) tag is useful. On the other hand, if the question is about how to sort an array in an Angular app, I don't think tagging it [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) is useful either. I have been know to remove tags in both these cases.