# Is it OK to put a tag on a question that is barely related to a question?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Very often I see some tech tag used with a question just because this tech happens to be used somewhere by OP.

Examples:

1. The OP is trying to integrate some library in his/her code and having problems with this. Instead of just tagging that library, he/she would also tag with, say, TypeScript because he/she wrote code in TypeScript, and also JavaScript because, you know, TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. He/she also may add the `WebPack` tag, guess why? Because he/she used WebPack to bundle his/her problematic code.
2. The OP is building a Node.js application and trying to make a query to MongoDB and has issues with this query. Not only will he/she tag it with MongoDB, but also he/she will tag with `nodejs` just because he/she wrote in Node.js. He/she may, as well, tag `javaScript` because Node.js runs JavaScript.

I wonder why not to add the Linux or Windows tags just because the OP uses those systems to run the problematic code.

As a result of this, while watching interesting tags, you will get A LOT of unrelated questions.

Should those tags be removed in such situations? Or, since they are somehow related, do they a have right to be there?

Comment: Imho, adding the language to a question about a framework/library is perfectly fine. Given that a lot of frameworks are available in more than one language, it is important for answers to know in which language they should answer or if they are even capable of answering the question.

Comment: "he would also add, say, typescript tag because he write code in ts". One reason to add language tag is for syntax highlighting. Although it can be accomplished by adding `<!-- language: lang-ts -->`

Comment: Would followers of the webpack tag answer that question? If no, the tag is incorrectly applied.

Comment: neither would followers of `node.js` tag answer to mongoDB related question

Comment: also SOME followers of `typescript` tag may answer to `angular` questions, but some may not. This is why I think that language tags should not be used unless the question is language specific

Comment: @BDL, you can show you language in code or define it in post. Anyway, using language tag with some specific library will help to small scope of interested in this particular library and will harm interests of much bigger scope of those who expected language specific questions.

Comment: Related [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357202/should-javascript-library-questions-have-the-javascript-tag), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364189/remove-language-tag-when-not-directly-about-that-language), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364189/remove-language-tag-when-not-directly-about-that-language)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the tags you have in your question. I can just tell you that a lot of Qt questions have a language tag, as do most OpenGL questions. I, (as a framework expert), wouldn't want to wade through a lot of questions just to note that they are in a language I don't know. On the other hand, you can simply exclude libraries from the search while in a language tag.

Comment: It is just fine when the question is broadly interesting to many users.  But that doesn't happen all that often, more typically it merely produces more close and downvotes.  Nothing that needs to be fixed, or could be fixed, that's how they learn to tag appropriately.  Don't hesitate to teach.

Answer (score 3):

For knowing when to apply certain tags, you need to know what a tags do. And what they do is essentially signaling. The signal they send is: this is the required knowledge to even being able to answer this question. The tags represent the skills to be worthy of participating on the race.

Now, if you signal people that would fail spectacularly in the race when you told them they were qualified, that would waste their time and the reader time.

Taken this two conditions into account, the better way to decide whenever or not to apply a tag is to remove all but one tag and see if someone with the knowledge of that sole tag is able to answer the question. If that isn't enough, then you start adding more tags depending on the knowledge you see that is lacking.