# What should the tag [machine-learning] mean?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, asking-questions, tag-disambiguation

So, there is a [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag. It is used mostly in two cases:

1. when a question is machine learning related, but language-agnostic. Those questions are revolving around AI techniques, not about the usage of ML frameworks. Examples of such posts can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297533/dealing-with-over-fitting-data-enlargement-cross-validation-rotation-augmenta) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291806/what-does-that-mean-vector-augmented-to-1).
2. when a question is about some ML framework in some language. It does not revolve around a technique, but rather around a concrete library for a concrete language. Some examples are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291517/how-do-you-form-data-to-make-an-array-of-n-features-and-n-samples-in-scikit-lear), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294675/why-does-naive-bayes-not-work-in-spark-mllib-pipeline-like-logistic-regression) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293955/hidden-markov-model-converging-to-one-state-using-hmmlearn).

I find it a little confusing - when filtering by this tag I usually am searching for first kind of answers, as I have more academical knowledge and experience with only some libraries.

Is there already some guideline which of those kinds should be tagged with [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning)? If not, I'd like to start a discussion on that topic.

If I were to propose some approach, I'd use the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag for first kind of questions, and remove it from the other kind. When a question is about a library, library tag should be used, for example there already are [hmmlearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hmmlearn) and [scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) tags.

---

I realized post-factum that one of those questions I quoted (about HMM) does not match any of the groups I've presented. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293955/hidden-markov-model-converging-to-one-state-using-hmmlearn) is about a HMM technique itself (so would fit first category), but provides an example using Python and hmmlearn (so it would also fit second group).

Again: Is there any guideline or agreed convention on how to tag such a question?

In my opinion, it should be left with the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag only, because [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [hmmlearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hmmlearn) are not really important to the question itself. On the other hand, the [hmmlearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hmmlearn) tag could be useful to people looking for examples on how to use that library.

---

I've found some questions on Meta that are loosely related to this issue:

- [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250876/language-tags-on-library-questions?rq=1) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289201/should-i-add-a-programming-language-tag-to-questions-about-frameworks?rq=1) could be useful when coming up with best practice on adding language tags on second kind of questions (and I would agree, for example I'd keep both [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) tags on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291517/how-do-you-form-data-to-make-an-array-of-n-features-and-n-samples-in-scikit-lear)).
- [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300571/what-is-the-point-of-generic-language-agnostic-tags-about-basic-programming-con?rq=1) one tackles the issue of whether the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag is needed at all, and some answers are in agreement with my proposal - to keep tags more general and avoid adding technology tags to technique questions.

Comment: I think questions which are not directly programming related may have a better place on http://ai.stackexchange.com/