# How to escape the `#` character in code?

Tags: support

Code after the base 10 instruction `10#` gets commented out [in the following bash code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35693189/2192488) ([revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35693189/revisions)) on Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to escape the `#` character in code, so that it does not get interpreted as the beginning of a comment?

Comment: There's a version of that on this very meta too: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: There isn't a proper bash or shell language, but `lang-none` can remove the failed highlighting.

Comment: Well, there is *supposed* to be syntax highlighting for bash (`lang-bash`), and it does get applied for the [tag:bash] tag, so this just looks like a Prettify bug to me.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, this is indeed a little bug in Prettify `lang-bash` which a good soul should [report](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) there. For the time being, `lang-none` saves my day. Thanks!