# How to treat CSS classes on IDs - they read like comments

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I just answered a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457299/css-bootstrap-megamenu?noredirect=1#comment64321690_38457299).

The problem is that the answer is CSS on IDs: CSS classes on IDs are rendered in the same style as comments.

[image: Wrong syntax-highlighting]

I'm not sure what the answer is, but I had to look twice at what I'd entered as it looks wrong.

Comment: You can specify [the language to use for syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). See my edit on your answer.

Comment: This is an age-old problem with prettify, which unfortunately isn't getting a fix anytime soon. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions

Comment: Just keep in mind that [tag:css] and [tag:html] use `lang-default` as the prettifier and  I explain [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677/578411) what that means