# Elm syntax highlighting does not render comments properly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

See this example:

```elm
test = 1 + 1
-- This test = 1 + 1 expression defines...
```

As a result, some people have been using Haskell syntax highlighting instead:

```hs
test = 1 + 1
-- This test = 1 + 1 expression defines...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax highlighting is based on [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), which [doesn't support](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work) Elm at the moment.

If Haskell syntax highlighting works well for Elm, it might be worthwhile to turn this into a *feature request*, requesting the Haskell syntax highlighting to be automatically applied to all questions tagged [elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elm). Otherwise, your only option is to join the Prettify project and add Elm support yourself (and wait for the changes to be applied by Stack Overflow).

Comment: Where does the syntax highlighting for Elm come from then? My feeling is that while being terrible when there is a comment, the Elm syntax highlighting is still better than Haskell otherwise.

Comment: @Zimmi48 it will just use the [default highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327673/what-is-the-default-language-for-the-syntax-highlighter).