# Add syntax highlight 'default' for tag [elm] (currently 'none')

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

For some time now I have been adding hints `<!-- language: lang-elm -->` to code snippets in elm language. Which gave the best result in syntax highlight but apparently was just forcing the *'default'* highlight. I suggest that all hintless code snippets in [elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elm) should be highlighted as *'default'*. I believe it can be done by mods.

Also is it possible to make *'default'* highlight for [Elm-language documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/elm/topics) hintless snippets?

Comment: Yeah, when you don't select none, and no matching prettifier is found is goes to the default: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677/578411

Comment: Related, not a duplicate: [Elm syntax highlighting does not render comments properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329694)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed the tag to default for now so you have *some* highlighting, but someone may want to go through other specific options to see which one highlights the language *best*. Default doesn't always do an amazing job.

The change automatically applies to documentation as well.