# GCC tag affects C++ syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614622/range-based-for-loop-with-existing-variable)

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtQqY.png)

`last` should not be highlighted as it is not a [keyword in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). Not sure why the [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) tag causes it to be highlighted as that's a compiler, not a language.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit
2. Remove the [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) tag
3. Make a minor edit in the textbox to force refresh

Comment: Could it be by chance, that [tag:gcc] is meant as a synonym for [tag:c]? Try tagging with [tag:g++].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think that is a bug. From [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

> If there's more than one tag that has syntax highlighting, it uses a default and lets Prettify infer what's the best language to use.

That question has multiple tags with a language hint on it (scroll to the end of the wiki):

- c++ -> [lang-cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info)
- c++11 -> [lang-cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info)
- gcc -> [lang-c](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gcc/info)
- visual-c++ -> [lang-cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2b%2b/info)

[for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-loop) has no language hint.

This means Prettify falls back to the Default which is all possible keywords of major languages smashed together. I explained more in depth how that works [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327673/what-is-the-default-language-for-the-syntax-highlighter/327677#327677).

If you want proper highlighting add the explicit prettifier to use `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->` or `<!-- language: lang-c -->` above the relevant code blocks.

Or even better: Don't mix C and C++, ever.

Comment: Can you be specific about which tags have the language hint? I don't see [anything on the list](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work) that's relevant except `cpp`.

Comment: You're right that it does use the default highlighter, as confirmed by Element Inspector. But I still think it's a bug if GCC is considered a valid language for the highlighter.

Comment: It is not a bug, the highlighter doesn't *know* which language to use. If you be explicit all works fine.

Comment: OK looks like πάντα ῥεῖ was on the money. [tag:gcc] has a language hint after all: "Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-c". Still, I find that pretty surprising and a "bug" on SE's part.

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ guy but if you think gcc shouldn't use lang-c as its prettifier you can open a support question for that. Make sure to check the current questions tagged gcc to verify that otherwise a bunch of other users get confused and start raising bugs.

Comment: It makes sense for [tag:gcc] to use `lang-c`. [tag:g++] should use `lang-cpp`. Obviously there's nothing wrong with tagging a C++ question with [tag:gcc], though, so this just proves that syntax highlighting is hard. Perhaps the best thing to do would be to ***remove*** the syntax highlighting hint from [tag:gcc] and [tag:g++] since those would never be correctly used without either [tag:c] or [tag:c++].

Comment: @CodyGray I think removing the highlighting would be best.  I don't see how you could use [tag:gcc] or [tag:g++] without a language tag when posting a code block.

Comment: @CodyGray I doubt that rule will be applicable across all tags and all type of questions. Where you have a choice but no knowledge about the context by applying a single lang-* you could be 100% wrong. By applying the lang-default, you can have luck and nobody notices ...

Comment: I didn't say to apply it to all tags...

Comment: @CodyGray Definitely agree that gcc should not have a language highlight. It's tag wiki says it refers to the Gnu Compiler Collection, not the old acronym of the Gnu C Compiler. Therefore it is just as justified to use it for C++, Java, Fortran, Ada or any other language GCC supports. Thus it should not have any associated language.