# Can someone explain why there is syntax highlighting with an unsupported language?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

The [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) tag has no syntax highlighting associated with it.
For example, [this post has code with no highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646007/verilog-can-not-save-multiple-values-in-register).

Also, Google Code Prettify does not have "verilog" as one of its supported languages.

I happened to stumble upon [this post which has highlighted code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329644/why-do-i-get-the-verilog-syntax-error-hdl-9-806).
I noticed it had the following manually inserted comment (when I "edit" the post):

```
<!-- language: lang-verilog -->
```

Since "verilog" is not supported, I thought this comment would be ignored.  But, surprisingly, it is applying some highlighting.  What language is being used?

---

For reference: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: The answer is in the very last paragraph of the canonical FAQ, the part headed "Tags", which is why I've closed this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

The highlighting will being attempted with the defaults which is just a set of basic rules - which is why you're seeing some highlighting in the question. It won't necessarily be right or indeed helpful.

As [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) points out in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677)

> There really is not a single language that is used as the default highlighter, it simply smashed together the keywords for major languages and handles two of the most common commenting styles and then tries to make the best of it.

It's also worth bearing in mind that:

> Behind the scenes, Stack Exchanges uses the tags on the question to infer the language you are using. If there's more than one tag that has syntax highlighting, it uses a default and lets Prettify infer what's the best language to use.

[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372)

though it doesn't apply in this case as there's only the one tag.

In a way, even though it has no effect now, adding the hint might still be useful if ever the language is supported. Though that depends on whether the current attempt at highlighting is useful or not. If it makes the code harder to read then I'd recommend removing the hint.

The other thing you can do, if you have enough reputation, is to ask a moderator to choose an existing language [on the tag's info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/verilog/info) that does a better job than the default.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I assumed it was using some default, but I just could find a doc that explicitly mentioned this.  So, I guess someone could use `lang-foobar` and still get default highlighting.

Comment: @toolic now you come to mention it you're right there.

Comment: Thanks again... I'll likely post a request for tag highlighting some day soon.