# Properties of binary and octal integer literals are not highlighted properly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Consider the syntax highlighting of this JS code:

```js
100.toString();   // SyntaxError
0100.toString();  // SyntaxError / legacy octal integer literal
0b100.toString(); // Binary integer literal
0o100.toString(); // Octal integer literal
0x100.toString(); // Hex integer literal
```

The `toString` identifier is highlighted like the digits in all but the last line.

It might make sense in the first line, because it's an unexpected identifier: the dot is treated as a decimal separator, not as a property accessor.

It might make sense in the second line, because legacy octal literals are non-standard and forbidden in strict mode.

However, identifiers after a binary or octal literal should be highlighted like after an hex one.

They are highlighted properly if I use two dots, but that's a SyntaxError

```js
0b100..toString(); // SyntaxError
0o100..toString(); // SyntaxError
```

Comment: That is a bug in prettify I'm afraid. Those should go on their issue tracker as stated here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/578411