# how to turn off colorization?

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

Easy question, I'm sure (and apologies if it's a dupe), but is there a way to turn off colorization in code fragments?  Perhaps by explicitly tagging the code as being in a specific language?  That is, over on SO under the [c] tag, if I write

```
Coca Cola 100
```

I see `Coca Cola` in blue, and `100` in red.  How do I turn this off?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874275/how-to-read-a-string-with-whitespaces-and-a-int-in-the-same-line-in-c/50875495#50875495) for context.

(And where's the documentation on SO's markup format?  I think I've seen it somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere on the Help Center just now.)

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-none -->` turns off syntax highlighting

Comment: Or, if it's not code, don't format it as code...

Comment: It is possible to set code formatting langauge like this as well: `\`\`\`lang-none
Coca Cola 100
\`\`\`` ref.: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can force the language of a code block by using `<!-- language: lang-<language> -->` html comment.

If you need to disable syntax color, use `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

Revision:https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50875495/revisions

As @Erik von Asmuth mentioned, `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` can be used for multiple code blocks in the post.

Comment: `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` would've saved you some work on that revision

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for editing the answer.  I still would have had trouble, because I wouldn't have known exactly where to put the HTML comment, whether it had to be indented along with the code, etc.

Comment: It should be a line above the code block without indentation. @SteveSummit

Comment: @SurajRao Got it, and now I've finally chased the link to [the FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) that explains this and has examples.

Comment: Could you specify WHERE to put this tag? When using triple-backtick-notation and putting it directly after the first three backticks it doesn't seem to have any effect in my post Where exactly do you put this tag when using triple-backtick-notation? I've got a piece of text words like 'is' are colorized due to involuntary syntax highlighting. Tried putting this tag directly after the first three backticks. Did not help. The post in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795109/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break/55971426#55971426

Comment: @Drkawashima might be an issue with the [new syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). Could be related to [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411447/javascript-highlighting-is-incorrect-when-defining-buffers-with-numbers-in-them). The old way still works. I have edited your post using that