# JavaScript highlighting is incorrect when defining buffers with numbers in them

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed that JavaScript in questions on Stack Overflow isn't quite highlighted correctly. I saw this in the following code:

```javascript
function getFileType(data) {
    let dataView = new Uint8Array(data);
}
```

As you may notice, the `Uint8Array` class should be fully highlighted, yet the `8` is ignored by the highlighter. This also happens for other arrays (e.g., `Uint16Array`, etc).

Comment: maybe better report it to https://github.com/highlightjs , see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter?r=SearchResults&s=4|55.2859

Comment: See [Issue #3252: (Javascript) Float32Array broken after 11.0.1](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3252)