# C++ syntax highlighting doesn't understand raw string literals

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, editor

In C++, one can define a [*raw string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
auto str = R"({"value": 42})"; // str is `{"value": 42}`
```

Unfortunately, on the main site, the syntax highlighting looks like:
[image: observed syntax highlighting on main site for c++ raw string literals]

It should look like:
[image: desired syntax highlighting on main site for c++ raw string literals]

It there something that can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) Please have a look at the accepted answer there, especially the part about reporting bugs.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes it does, *thumbsup*

Comment: I don't have an access to my github account currently, if someone have [a few minutes to report the bug](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues), I'd highly appreciate it :)