# Where should bug reports and feature requests about syntax highlighting be made, now that the Prettify repository is no longer accepting new issues?

Tags: support, meta, syntax-highlighting, bug-reporting-process, feature-request-process

In the [FAQ on syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), it states that Stack Overflow uses Google Prettify, an external syntax highlighter, and issues and requests with it should be reported to them since SE doesn't maintain that highlighter.

However, in April 2020, Google [announced that Prettify had been discontinued and would no longer be maintained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint), and at the same time, the repository was marked read-only and is no longer accepting new issue filings.

Given that, if I find a bug with the syntax highlighter, or have a feature idea for it, where should I file it? Should I file them here on Meta?

(This question is not about what SE should do to their current syntax highlighting setup; I've already started a discussion on Meta.SE about it, linked above. Rather, it's about where *users* should file issues about it.)

Comment: Until we get an answer to [your other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint), regarding whether SE is going to maintain their own fork of Prettify or switch to another highlighter, I suspect the answer to *this* question is `/dev/null`. There's no real point in filing bugs against something where they cannot be fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps filing them on meta is a good idea anyway, to help advance the idea that SE should do something about the highlighter situation?

Comment: Note: I [asked about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348772) in the context of the current CommonMark migration. Answer: They will keep the highlighter for now, but it sounded like they are open for changes after the migration is done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)