# Clojure code highlight is broken

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I am wondering why nobody has reported this issue before.

It looks like the highlighter incorrectly picks symbols at the end of words.

[image]

This is a picture from this question:
[Stuck with type hints in clojure for generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122495/stuck-with-type-hints-in-clojure-for-generic-class)

I first thought that this is due to incorrect language detection, but adding `lang-clj` didn't fix it.

Comment: Bonus: the repo has been archived. There's also a post on this here on meta, but I can't find it - SE will likely have to implement a new highlighter (write one from scratch or use a library) at some point. In the meanwhile, considering the repo has been archived, this probably won't be fixed.

Comment: @Zoe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398275/where-should-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-about-syntax-highlighting-be-made and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347738/google-code-prettify-has-been-officially-discontinued-its-time-for-se-to-maint

Comment: @Zoe, thanks for comment. But provided answer is irrelevant here because this is not about detecting language but in actual highlight of keywords.

Comment: There's still nothing SE can do.

Comment: @sage444 that is the defacto dup for questions about the syntax highlighting.  The answer covers generally what to do if something isn't working right (the 3rd and 4th sections of the answer).  But for the reason's rene mentioned, it likely won't be addressed.  The canonical answer probably needs updating

Comment: @psubsee2003 are you about addressing my concerns into `/dev/null` :)) ?

Comment: @Zoe, thanks finally I got it

Comment: IMHO is worth investing some efforts into this issue rather than into another "+1" buttons