# TypeScript syntax highlighting not working correctly (anymore?)

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Martijn Pieters is right, this is answered by [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

**[Here's the feature request to enable TypeScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-enable-highlight-jss-support-for-typescript).**

---

I don't recall seeing this problem with the previous syntax highlighting library, but the current one gets TypeScript pretty markedly wrong. This code:

```
function exampleOverload(a: number): number;
function exampleOverload(a: number[]): number[];
function exampleOverload(a: number | number[]): number | number[] {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a.map(v => v * 2);
    }
    return a * 2;
}
```

currently gets highlighted like this on SO:

[image]

Note the almost random, and inconsistent, application of the orange color.

This happens whether you use code fences with `typescript` or use four spaces of indent and allow the language to be auto-detected from the tags. It's also what you get when you apply JavaScript formatting to that code.

Maybe it would make sense to ensure that the replacement works for the major languages on the site *before* switching to it rather than after?

Comment: Prettify had loads of problems too; we now have a different lightweight syntax highlighter with its own set of different issues. At least this library is actively being maintained. This particular issue will need to be reported to the highlight.js project.

Comment: Can you try marking the code block as lang-default (I see the typescript tag uses lang-js, might have worked for prettify but maybe highlight,js is better at doing the defailt thing here)

Comment: @rene - As I mentioned, I used code fences with `typescript` (and also tag-based auto-detetion). Is that not how you say specifically what language to use? I'd be thrilled if this is user error. :-)

Comment: TypeScript is not one of the languages that's supported, so specifying it will do nothing. See the [list of supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). Note that if syntax highlighting used to be okay for TypeScript but now horribly fails, that might be an excellent reason to ask SE to add TypeScript support. @Martijn, since the issue is that SE doesn't support TS we shouldn't report it to the highlight.js folks.

Comment: @ErikA - Wow, that's **really** irritating, since TypeScript is [supported by highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md). But thanks, you've just saved me bothering the `highlight.js` folks for no good reason! :-)

Comment: @ErikA that answer is still largely relevant to Prettify, not highlight.js (_"Each language is grouped together based on how they appear in the Prettify JS file that Stack Exchange loads"_).

Comment: @CodeCaster The language support is actual, language support hasn't changed by migrating from Prettify to Highlight.js, since SE actively removed languages that are not on that list. Some details, however, are out of date.

Comment: @ErikA - If I could try your patience, where in [the question you pointed to in a comment you deleted when I edited mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) (or elsewhere) is it confirmed that languages were removed? I just want to cite it when asking that one of the most popular languages on the planet, which is supported by the new engine, be added to the list. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Under _What’s changing about how I write posts?_, _However, we are not adding support for any new languages at this time, instead choosing to keep the initial changeset simple and aiming for current feature parity instead_. I glossed over it on the first read too, see my deleted answer there.

Comment: @ErikA: if hightlight.js specifically has TypeScript support then a feature request to add TS to the languages supported here might be warranted. If there is no no TS support in highlight.js then requesting that feature from the highlight.js folks would be the next step here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Highlight.js has TypeScript support, it's even in the default set of languages (not in a separate module), else I wouldn't have suggested a feature request here of course ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Curiously enough, that's what I was doing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-enable-highlight-jss-support-for-typescript I verified that highlight.js does a better job of highlighting TypeScript code when it knows it's TypeScript, even if it's using its generic engine (which I think it  is). :-)

Comment: @ErikA - Did the FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354679/please-enable-highlight-jss-support-for-typescript

Comment: Many thanks @MartijnPieters and ErikA for pointing me at the various posts that address the above.