# Is there a way to fix the syntax highlighting for PHP code blocks that include HTML?

Tags: support, bug, syntax-highlighting

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906488/285587):.

> [image]

It seems the highlighter cannot handle more than a pair of HTML attributes, failing the next one and ruining the rest of the code.

A proper syntax highlighting is very important in programming, offering enormous help in both readability and hunting bugs, saving one a lot of time and effort. While struggling through failed highlighting does exactly the opposite. Given Stack Overflow is a site for programmers, it's hard to underestimate such bugs.

Is there any command to make it work properly? Or if it's a bug, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Apparently [the problem there is the mixup between HTML and PHP](https://cln.sh/CHZDZV). The syntax highlighter is encouraging good practices. :P

Comment: I appreciate the joke but there is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62803167/285587) with neither PHP or HTML involved. Quotes are definitely a sore point of the highlighter

Comment: On this other example, the code that's problematic is **python** code on a question about SQL. The code in question is not appropriately language-tagged, so the syntax-highlighter trips by trying to apply SQL highlighting. If properly edited, without the `a')` of the second and third code blocks, it looks like [this](https://cln.sh/75hJX9).

Comment: Moral of the story: the tools can only do so much if used incorrectly. Don't ask what the syntax highlighter can do for you, but what can you do for the syntax highlighter (hint: editing is fine)

Comment: I see, thanks. Now it makes sense

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39831043/285587). Here is mixing of PHP and SQL to blame, I presume. Is there a way to mark the language directly in the post/code block?

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Aha, now it's all clear. Got my answer. Thanks a lot!