# Bug in JavaScript code colors

Tags: bug, code-formatting

The following JavaScript code:

```javascript
let hsv2hsl = (h,s,v,l=v-v*s/2, m=Math.min(l,1-l)) => [h,m?(v-l)/m:0,l];
```

colors are wrong (starting from `/2` which is interpreted as comment):

Light mode:

[image]

Dark mode:

[image]

### Update

The duplicate question suggests that I should report this bug directly in the *highlight.js* GitHub repository - I do it [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2905), but they closed the bug and stated that this *will not be fixed* [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2905#issuecomment-739305999).

PS: For instance, on [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle), JavaScript coloring [works properly](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/bdsjuq8p/) - so it is possible.

[image]

Comment: I see the same formatting here on Meta with the normal light mode: https://i.imgur.com/V9O5T3I.png

Comment: It seems to be interpreted as a regex literal rather than a comment. (It's using `class="hljs-regexp"`.)

Comment: Is this a bug in hightlight.js, in which case see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can that be target for a bug?!?

Comment: @Scratte did you look at it? *"How do I report a bug or request a new language?"* is one of the points it covers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. I mistake. I kind of realized it a little late though. I find the process disheartening. I'm pretty sure one will need a github account to even report a bug then :( With all the bugs I see on the highlighting reporting bugs could also be a full time occupation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I put comment on "What is syntax highlighting..." what do you think about this? I just report this bug here - and hope that responsible SO stuff will take care of such basic and shaming bug... (by report it further and make other necessarily actions)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I'm not interested, thanks, just telling you where to look.

Comment: I think there are too many problems with this to be addressed. 1. Stack picked a buggy highlighter. 2. No one tested it properly. 3. Despite 1 & 2, Stack doesn't want to be middle man. 4. Users gets frustrated. Every day I see something and think "What a horrible highlighting! Not bothered to read the rest of this code.." 5. Only a few users will report bugs. Personally, I'm not inclined.

Comment: Possibly related bug report: [(javascript) division and regular expressions can get confused and break highlighting](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2050)

Comment: @AndrewT. thank you to make this effort and point it out - this motivate me to report bug directly to higlight.js [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2905)

Comment: That's still the relevant dupe; if highlight.js can't fix it, it'll stay like that. Unless JSFiddle is using highlight.js it's not a relevant example; it's obviously not *globally* impossible. And please stop hassling everyone.

Comment: JsFiddle can afford to have a parser because they only have to cater for JavaScript. HighlightJS has to cater for a much broader range of languages. For SE it is important that highlighting support comes with an acceptable performance hit for all users and that they don't have the burden to run their own highlighter. It is a good enough. If that doesn't work for you then you're out of luck here.