# Dockerfile syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

From what I read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), and [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md); I expected there would be syntax highlighting for `Dockerfile` files.

But I've tried it to apply highlighting to one answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65320366/1426539), but it never shows.

I've tried using both `docker` and `dockerfile` as language hints, with the same (lack of) results.

(Just realized that on the question the asker attempted it using `Dockerfile` as language hint, but again, no visible results).

After helpful prodding by rene, I realized that the language is not currently supported from the list that's posted within [the corresponding post in uber-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/348149).

Following advice from zcoop98, I've also tried using `lang-dockerfile` and `lang-docker`, but the results appear to be hit-and-miss:
[image]

But maybe that's the intended result, and my expectations are the problem.

This is now a request that this highlighting is enabled, and if it's actually enabled and what I see when using `lang-docker` is what we got... well, to see if we can get anything better than that.

We have hats. Now we need more variously coloured source-code files.

Comment: No docker here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100

Comment: Oh, I just went to the link with the "list of highlight.js supported languages", and I assumed (incorrectly) that if it was there it should work. I guess I should turn this into a request so that it gets enabled?

Comment: Yeah, but don't have high hopes, certainly not in the 6 to 8 weeks timeframe. Possible related/useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355233/add-syntax-highlighting-support-for-nginxconf Cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355494/add-syntax-highlighting-support-for-dockerfiles

Comment: Another note- using "docker" or "dockerfile" as the language hint will actually tell the highlighter to look to those respective *tags* for the language hint. Neither has a highlighter language assigned to it, so it's no different than "lang-default", which is the highlighter's best guess for language. In the future, to specify a certain language in particular, use the "lang-" prefix for language hints to specify a language, eg. "lang-docker" or "lang-dockerfile".

Comment: @zcoop98 Curiously `lang-dockerfile` produces **some** highlighting. Not a particularly nice one, though.

Comment: Since Dockerfiles are usually mostly shell commands, I manually mark them as `lang-sh`.  That doesn't highlight the Docker keywords, but it's definitely less random than the default.

Comment: [Highlight.js maintainer here] Pretty sure Docker is another one of the grammars we DO support quite well, but SE choses not to bundle because of size/speed considerations.

Comment: why is dockerfile still not supported on stackoverflow? i still can't style it to a fully-readable block?