# Is there a comprehensive list of languages the code highlighter supports?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

The triple backtick is my go to, to format snippets of code.

```` ``` ````

I regularly use them like:

- ```` ```json ```` for [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- ```` ```py ```` for [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)

... and many more

Does a list of the linters Stack Overflow supports exist?

For example:

> I tried to lint a `Dockerfile` to no avail. Is it ```` ```dockerfile ````
> , ```` ```docker ```` , ... it is even supported?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403721/dockerfile-syntax-highlighting

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: NB, "Stack Snippets" is the name of a specific feature that allows _runnable_ front-end code (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). It does not refer to just any "block" or "section" etc. of code included in a post.

Comment: @RobertLongson awesome thanks!

I am surprised to see dockerfile format not being included. But thanks a lot

Comment: Meta.SO dupe: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) (which links to [the master list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) above)

Comment: What do linters have to do with syntax highlighting?