# /help/formatting says we use Prettify, but we use highlight.js now

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting says:

> Code blocks can be highlighted using [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). In many cases, the syntax highlighting language [will be inferred from the question's tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

But currently our site uses highlight.js for syntax highlighting. Details here: [Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/341401)

So how about updating this paragraph? For instance:

> Code blocks can be highlighted using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). In many cases, the syntax highlighting language [will be inferred from the question's tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274371).

Diff:

1. Google Prettify -> highlight.js
2. Use a FAQ link for the inference of a syntax highlighting language because the post currently linked is old and says we use Prettify.

Also how about updating here:

> You can use either [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), like ...

to this:

> You can use either [one of the supported language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), like ...

Comment: Same for the [tag wiki](/tags/syntax-highlighting/info).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Exactly. I wrote and requested an edit for the tag wiki of [syntax-highlighting]. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow, uh... that's a bit embarrassing! Thanks for catching this error. I've updated the page as you recommended. Please let me know if I've missed anything.