# Possible markdown rendering bug (strong/bold text in code blocks)

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

If you enclose text with two asterisks, it will be displayed in bold letters. This shouldn't be the case in code blocks (I assume). When you edit or ask a question, the preview is displayed as expected. But the question is displayed differently after you finished editing it. The asterisks are still shown in the code block, but the text is displayed in bold letters.

I cannot reproduce this here on meta. Example:

```
**bold**
not bold
```

But have a look at the code block of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69564897/11942268). Screenshot for future reference (it happens on light *and* dark theme btw.):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) - See the _"How do I report a bug or request a new language?"_ section.

Comment: _"the preview is displayed as expected. But the question is displayed differently after you finished editing it"_ It still looked bold/strong for me even while editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bold came from the syntax highlighting. I updated the question to use no syntax highlighting using the following notation and the bold went away.

````
```none 
the code...
```
````

The system was guessing that that code was markdown.   `**` indicates something that is bold in markdown, so bolding for that flavor of syntax highlighting seems appropriate.

You can verify it with:

````
```markdown
**bold**
not bold
```
````

```markdown
**bold**
not bold
```

Comment: The [[tag:powershell]] tag implies "default" syntax highlighting. Which is... best guess. Perhaps the Highlight.JS engine highlighted the code as if it were Markdown?

Comment: It was using the markdown syntax highlighting. You can see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69564897/1) when inspecting the HTML. (It uses the `language-markdown` class.)

Comment: Yes, it was markdown, updated my answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, because [_"PowerShell is not supported by the Stack Exchange version of highlight.js"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/348196), which is why this is a duplicate of the FAQ post.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Good find! _Noted._ :)