# TypeScript syntax highlighting broken in this question

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

The problematic code (with `lang-typescript` code fence):

```typescript
type ParseFunc<OutT, InT> = (val: InT) => OutT;

declare const parseString: ParseFunc<string, unknown>;

declare const makeParseObject: <FPs extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<any, any>}> (fieldParsers: FPs)
    => ParseFunc<ParseObjectResult<FPs>, unknown>;
type ParseObjectResult<FPs extends {[s: string]: ParseFunc<any, unknown>}> =
    {[F in keyof FPs]: ParseResult<FPs[F]>}
type ParseResult<P> = P extends ParseFunc<infer OutT, unknown> ? OutT : never;
```

Screenshot of the syntax highlighting on 2021-11-20, with Firefox 94.0.1, macOS 11.6.  I get the same thing on Chrome 95.0.4638.69.
[image: Screenshot of syntax highlighting]

It looks ok in the TypeScript Playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QGIFcB2BjAPAeXWABUAaKASU2ID4oBeKACgDc4AbALkuoEoG6hEgG4AUKIAmEbO0TRsAe0xJgUMIhQBlYAgCWmAObd4yNFjwq9h8lgDWmBQHdMNMZOmyE8pSqgBbOFsIExR8ACMAK2lgblxUGCQoCAAPYAhMCUSAbwBtJG5LfQMAXWMNMxxcOEwQcmqQGgBfOiYAM10IdgkQiGRueKReUSgRgVhyjEqe8KjsYAAlCCR0dmA4hJobTHsnFzFQSHHTGejF5dX1xJS0jOy8gp0i0qOUSbx6rZ3nJrp6YdHcqgoPooEEQApWlABs8emcVmsBjlUMUmqIDtBYUt4bgYL9YElUulMi8Knh9K1elAhGQoHYHN8oAB+KlEYhQbiYCAsXrCIA).

When I switch the Playground to other TypeScript versions (e.g. 3.3.3, 4.0.5) it still looks ok.

Comment: You may want to have a read of the FAQ [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274371/215552). It has nothing to do with how the Playground works; the Playground only needs to worry about one language; SO has to worry about all of them.

Comment: This is a bug in the highlight.js highlighter. You'll need to file a bug in [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js). In other words, this [can be reproduced](https://jsfiddle.net/650rLwyd/) using the typescript language definition for both the version of highlight.js which SE uses, 11.0.1, and the most recent released version, 11.3.1.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I included the Playground link to show that the code is actually valid TypeScript, that's all.

Comment: @Makyen: Thanks, will do!

Comment: @Makyen: With your JSFiddle (thanks for that!), when I change `version` to `"11.3.1"` the highlighting improves a lot. I'm guessing SE upgrades periodically?

Comment: @KannanGoundan I'm not aware of what schedule, if any, SE uses for upgrading highlight.js versions. I don't recall seeing anything mentioned definitively, or even in passing, which would indicate there's a schedule.