# Syntax Formatting Bug with Method Parameter Attributes in C#

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting of attributes on method parameters in C# seems buggy.

The code at the [bottom of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794558/adding-code-to-methods-with-parameters-that-are-decorated-with-attribute) doesn't render the first attribute correctly.

I've replicated the code and provided a screenshot of the issue for posterity, in case the rendering engine is updated or the question changes.

```cs
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    ValidateCreateUser(name, email, dateOfBirth);  // You'd add this line yourself
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

[image: Code rendering issue]

It would appear to me as though the first `ValidateParameter` attribute should be highlighted the same as the other two.

Comment: Syntax highlighting on SE comes via the external component highlight.js. If highlight.js classify the code wrong, a bug should be filled in their [github repo](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js), or even better, submit a PR with a fix. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/274372#how-do-i-report-a-bug-or-request-a-new-language

Comment: Or request a version update if it has already been fixed. For example, the [new syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) (2020-09-08) was [updated to a new version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378548/syntax-highlighting-changes-in-the-middle-of-a-token-resolved-in-a-later-versio/379238#379238) (11.5.1) on 2022-06-02 (latest at that time).