# Add code highlighting for the Ballerina tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Currently, the [Ballerina tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ballerina/info) does not have code highlighting associated with it. Can we add the Ballerina language syntax highlighting to the questions that are tagged with `ballerina`?

This question was according to this answer: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

- It seems like Highlight.js is not yet supporting Ballerina, but adding `<!-- language-all: lang-ballerina -->` to a question on SO seems to enable syntax highlighting for Ballerina.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) Also, [Ballerina is not yet supported by highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md)

Comment: @RobertLongson Seems it is not supported by HightlightJS, but when you add `<!-- language-all: lang-ballerina -->`, the code starts highlighting.

Comment: @AndrewT. I asked this following the answer to the question you mentioned. As per that answer we need to add a `feature-request` to update the syntax highlighting for a particular tag.

Comment: "*but when you add `<!-- language-all: lang-ballerina -->`, the code starts highlighting.*" please read the FAQ once again. The language is not yet supported, thus highlight.js *guessed and picked* one from the available languages. In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74865016/2821954) is [`language-go`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEkIG.png)

Comment: Thanks, we will look into adding Ballerina to HighlightJS.