# Status of the [spam] & [offensive] flags is missing

Tags: support, bug, flags

Today I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388150/block-all-usa-visitors-from-registering) that was asking about ways to block people from the USA, and naturally they accumulated downvotes. The user then got *slightly* hot-headed and decided to interpret the downvotes as "blocking people from the USA is a really stupid idea", resulting in abuse.

As a result I then flagged the question as [offensive], then went into my flag history to find that there was no status by the [offensive] flag.

Since the flag was already handled, I created a test question from an old unused account of mine and flagged it as [spam]:

[image]

Any other flag type besides [offensive] and [spam] are labeled with "active" when they have not been answered; additionally, when [offensive] or [spam] flags are answered, they *are* marked with "helpful", as expected:

[image]

Is this a bug, or an actual feature?

Comment: The old design didn't show them as active either. There's a [long-standing request from 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190843/active-state-for-spam-flags) to have it fixed. Still nothing.

Comment: About using code formatting for emphasis: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: Problem is, the people downvoting really do need an attitude adjustment.  Downvotes on the main site do not work the same way they do on Meta.  And a question can be off topic (for being related to networking, not programming) without being bad / downvote worthy.  I really have to question the comment you left on the sole answer, because the question had not suggested that OP was aware of geolocation databases.  Was there a ninja edit I'm not seeing?

Comment: @BenVoigt The question suggested that the OP *was* in fact aware of it as they suggested it themselves. This Meta question isn't about that question; please keep on-topic.