# A convention for marking errors?

Tags: discussion, edits

I would say extremely often, people on SO are asking about errors in their code.  In fact, this happens **extremely** often.

One thing that seems extremely variant between posts is how those errors/stacktraces are marked.  Some of them have it in plaintext, some have it in bold, some have it marked as code, some have it marked in quotes, or a combination of those.

**I would propose that a standard be made for how errors/stacktraces are marked.  For example, denoting an error by quoting and marking as code.**

---

### This is how you might see errors now

1. `java.myerror.myerror on line n`
2. java.myerror.myerror on line n
3. **java.myerror.myerror on line n**
4. *java.myerror.myerror on line n*

I think you get the point

---

### The proposal (Slightly repetitive, but keep reading):

All errors/stacktraces are denoted by a quote around marked as code.

For example:

> `java.myerror.myerror on line n`

---

What does the community think?  Is this something that should be standardized?  In my opinion, it should be.

Comment: So you want to *avoid* distinguishing error text from code by intentionally preventing people from using formatting in a way that visually distinguishes entirely separate concepts by using a formatting designed to display code to display non-code content?

Comment: Using [`<samp>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42692/could-samp-support-be-added-to-stack-exchange) for this would probably work out well.

Comment: Unrelated, but why would we have an [tag:errors] tag?

Comment: A related discussion on [preferences for formatting error logs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286706/how-should-compiler-errors-linker-errors-and-logs-be-formatted) (not quite a duplicate, I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as stack trace is readable any formatting is fine. More important part that usually missed is to show code and exact location of error.

I would avoid formatting code in any alternative way that just code just to highlight error line. Most languages support comments - marking error with code comment in source is best approach I've seen:

I.e. for curly-bracket languages (C/C++/C#/Java/JavaScript/...) double slash is good line comment to indicate error:

```
method();
method2(); // line that throws FooBar exception
moreCalls();
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's clear, that's good enough.  Changing the formatting of content from one entirely clear and understandable formatting to another is just pointless busywork.

If it's not clear what content in the question is code, an error, or the author's text, then you should be editing the post to whatever formatting you feel makes them all suitably clear.