# How can I make better edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

It seems like my edit suggestions are getting rejected left and right but I'm not sure why. I work hard on each edit, trying to improve as much as possible. I take at least a couple of minutes per edit.

I scan through the entire post searching for parts that can be improved. Not only do I fix spelling and grammar, but I also make posts more concise. I delete entire sentences that are not needed and make posts more readable

I have no idea why I'm having so little success here. Is there anything I could do better?

Comment: As a starter suggestion, go to your profile, select "all actions" below your informational boxes, then "suggestions" below that. Each link labelled as "accepted edit", "rejected edit", and "pending edit" are links to the reviews of those edits. Check your rejected edits there and see what reasons for the rejections were given. Also check out [the proposed faq for good edits.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall, your suggestions are ok but not amazing.  Here's a few things I noticed you are doing well:

- Properly removing noise like "Thanks" and other irrelevant/redundant stuff
- Improving the grammar of posts

Things you can improve on:

- Better tag selection.  For example, you sometimes add broad tags like [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) when they're not really necessary.
- Better use of formatting, especially for error messages.  [You can use code indentation with a syntax formatting HTML comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286749/4320665) like `<!-- language: lang-none -->`
- Fixing indentation of code (when possible, so not in Python) so that the code is more consumable

Comment: Biggest reason for me to reject/reject-edit suggested edits: they didn't remove "thanks" or "hi, my name is bob" fluff.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I'll admit I'm a bit trigger happy when adding tags and some might be over the top. Also Some of the edits I make are from old posts (few months old) that I dug up on a search. I'll focus more on newer posts

Answer (score 3):

Your [suggestion history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5680735/user5680735?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) shows that 8 out of 60 suggested edits were rejected; this is really not a bad record at all. Looking at some specific rejections, I personally wouldn't have rejected [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12940137), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11892777) was rejected automatically because it conflicted with somebody else's edit (that happens from time to time). Keep in mind that reviewers aren't perfect human beings either, but overall I would say: please continue what you're doing.