# Please add support for the <samp> tag

Tags: feature-request, design

From MDN, [`<samp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/samp)

> The HTML `<samp>` element is an element intended to identify sample
>   output from a computer program. It is usually displayed in the
>   browser's default monotype font (such as Lucida Console).

This is of course very useful on all the "code" sites, but particularly also in documentation. Can we have a decent CSS style for it?

Usage example:

```
The following should appear on your screen:

<samp>sklivvz@DESKTOP-FP94G5S:~$ uname -r
3.4.0+</samp>
```

Expected output should look like a terminal or *at least* be `<pre>`:

The sample should appear on your screen:

[image]

Actual output does not even conform to expected HTML5 behavior:

The following should appear on your screen:

sklivvz@DESKTOP-FP94G5S:~$ uname -r
3.4.0+

Comment: Even better would be some sort of modifier for Markdown's blockquote syntax (akin to the prettify hints for code blocks), as that'd provide a fallback here (*rendering it* as `<samp>` would still be nice). I vaguely recall discussing something like this a couple years back, primarily for logcat listings.

Comment: Presumably he could have made a business case for this, but making it happen would still, presumably, require the same people to sign off on allowing it to happen? The only difference, I imagine, in asking *now* is that the request is more public. Though I can't imagine that's going to make a difference, really.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sure more users are just as disappointed as you seem to be but this request can have some merit in area's where SO Inc. is still invested in, like Docs. Not sure why you need to lash out like that to former devs as I doubt individuals can or should be held responsible for the direction a company moves to.

Comment: @HansPassant working there or not, one goes through meta for these feature requests. As for "you could have done it"... I doubt it. I know SO hasn't been developing the core codebase much in the last few years, in fact that's not unrelated to why I'm a *former* developer.

Comment: @Shog9 sure but that's a complex request and the markdown should still render to `<samp>`. One step at a time. Let's see if we can get 2 hours of a designer to implement a style on a minor HTML5 tag first.

Comment: Oh yes please! And if it happens, could we have it on other sites on the network? I can see this being handy on the rest of the trilogy, U&L, AU....

Comment: I'm being pedantic, but when you say "Expected output should look like a terminal or _at least_ be `<pre>`", why would you expect that? The default browser style for <samp> is only the monospace font, nothing else.

Comment: @MrLister why would the default browser style be the expected behavior of this feature request?

Comment: What is the advantage of such a tag over a regular code block?

Comment: @Sklivvz Otherwise it wouldn't be expected, now would it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The number of times I've typed <!-- language: lang-none --> has to be into the hundreds at this point....

Comment: I've read it as "please add the support for the <spam> tag" :D

Comment: *Actual output does not even conform to expected HTML5 behavior* Not strictly true as the output is simply rendered as `<p>` tags instead of `<samp>`. However, I would really like to see this feature for console output, logs, probably even error messages.

Comment: when to use samp tag and when use output tag ?

Comment: @WalleCyril well you can't use either yet. But imagine `samp` would render something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmQqPX

Comment: Is this related to [How to format logs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286706/509868)? If yes, you might want to mention this explicitly.

Comment: Any discussion or implementation work on block syntax in Markdown should probably review and track [Pandoc's discussion of div properties](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/168). Of course there is no requirement to use the same syntax implementation, but there are few angles left undiscussed and it probably makes sense to implement them the same way.