# Edit rejected, but someone reposted my edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I've [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585763/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-singlevaluedassociationfield) to make it more readable. However, this has been [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17318137).

The same user who rejected it [appears to have edited exactly like my version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32585763/revisions) which they rejected!

How do I handle this? I'm trying to spend some time every day to improve readability of questions, but things like this negate the incentive.

Comment: Huh.  Looks like they didn't like you marking up the error as code.  IMHO they should have just done an improve and edit to fix that then reject and edit.

Comment: I can agree with the error not being code, but to reject is a bit over the top. Those four spaces is not nothing compared to all that was corrected. Either accept and edit as stated above or just accept and live with the error being code. Who really cares anyway?

Comment: @Andreas That's not the only difference between both versions and a proper formatting does matter.

Comment: @Tom yes, but if you compare what is wrong with what is correctly edited then there is no reason to reject. Some questions are edited 10 times before everyone is satisfied. What other difference is there?

Comment: @Andreas: **"What other difference is there?"** - Although they are clearly visible, I'll list them: no "this", the chopped method calls kept their indentation, no line break after the link, "I" hasn't been edited to "I've", the last sentence has been removed.

Comment: @Tom clearly visible is a loose term. On a computer with both open at the same time, yes maybe. On a phone forced to "full site" and tiny text and not (in an easy way) able to have both open at the same time, not so much. There may be differences but they are not clearly visible to all.

Comment: Error code is supposed to be formatted as code, not as if you're quoting the compiler/IDE, according to this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286706/how-should-compiler-errors-linker-errors-and-logs-be-formatted It should not have been rejected for that reason.