# Possibly incorrect code formatting error preventing submission

Tags: support, code-formatting

Unsure if this will post here, but I'm unable to submit the contents of the indented notes into the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54100609/10089398).  I'm getting the blocking error that I must indent all code with 4 spaces. The preview works fine, and I'd rather not debug this with BBEdit or Notepad++ (unless this is a new expectation I should have when posting here).

Advice appreciated.

> **Code from article**
>
> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Creates a minimal allocation / GC efficient socket awaitable class
> /// Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/
> /// </summary>
> public sealed class SocketAwaitable : INotifyCompletion
> {
>     private readonly static Action SENTINEL = () => { };
>
>     internal bool m_wasCompleted;
>     internal Action m_continuation;
>     internal SocketAsyncEventArgs m_eventArgs;
>
>     public SocketAwaitable(SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
>     {
>         if (eventArgs == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(“eventArgs”);
>         m_eventArgs = eventArgs;
>         eventArgs.Completed += delegate
>         {
>             var prev = m_continuation ?? Interlocked.CompareExchange(
>                 ref m_continuation, SENTINEL, null);
>             if (prev != null) prev();
>         };
>     }
>
>     internal void Reset()
>     {
>         m_wasCompleted = false;
>         m_continuation = null;
>     }
>
>     public SocketAwaitable GetAwaiter() { return this; }
>
>     public bool IsCompleted { get { return m_wasCompleted; } }
>
>     public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
>     {
>         if (m_continuation == SENTINEL ||
>             Interlocked.CompareExchange(
>                 ref m_continuation, continuation, null) == SENTINEL)
>         {
>             Task.Run(continuation);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void GetResult()
>     {
>         if (m_eventArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
>             throw new SocketException((int)m_eventArgs.SocketError);
>     }
> }
>
>  /// <summary>
>  /// Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/12/15/awaiting-socket-operations/
>  /// </summary>
>  public static class SocketExtensions
>  {
>     public static SocketAwaitable ReceiveAsync(this Socket socket,  SocketAwaitable awaitable)
>     {
>         awaitable.Reset();
>         if (!socket.ReceiveAsync(awaitable.m_eventArgs))
>             awaitable.m_wasCompleted = true;
>         return awaitable;
>     }
>
>     public static SocketAwaitable SendAsync(this Socket socket,
>         SocketAwaitable awaitable)
>     {
>         awaitable.Reset();
>         if (!socket.SendAsync(awaitable.m_eventArgs))
>             awaitable.m_wasCompleted = true;
>         return awaitable;
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> Article Comments:
>
> > **Matthew** 
> >     Hi Stephen, thanks for the nice solution. Unfortunately I am running into a problem on the subsequent calls. The first call executes
> >     Task.Run(continuation) consistently and the subsequent call throws
> >     exception that says "An attempt was made to transition a task to a
> >     final state when it had already completed.". I understand that this
> >     error occurs in "..Builder.SetResult(result)" compiler generated code.
> >     Also, I noticed that "…Builder.Task.Status" is "WaitingForActivation".
> >     Do you know what's going on? Thanks in advance.
>
> ```
> public async Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] data)
> {
>     if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
>         return 0;
>
>     Socket socket = (Socket)this.sendSAEA.UserToken;
>     // set data
>     this.sendSAEA.SetBuffer(0, data.Length);
>     Array.Copy(data, this.sendSAEA.Buffer, data.Length);
>     // create awaitable
>     SocketAwaitable awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(this.sendSAEA);
>     await socket.SendAsync(awaitable);
>     //// return number of bytes transferred
>     return this.sendSAEA.BytesTransferred;
> }
> ```
>
> > **Stephen**
> >     @Matthew: Sounds like there's a problem in your code that's resulting in the compiler-provided delegate being invoked multiple times.  What
> >     does your code look like?
>
> .
>
> > *Matthew*
> >     @Stephen, 
> >     thanks for looking in this. 
> >     SocketAwaitable and SocketExtensions classes are exact copy from your code. > > And here is my method that calls Socket.SendAsync()
> >     method. 
> >     Where 'sendSAEA' is SocketAsyncEventArgs from the pool.
>
> .
>
> > **Stephen** 
> >     @Mathew: Your code is creating a new SocketAwaitable each time, wrapping a SocketAsyncEventArgs that's getting reused
> >     repeatedly.  Each time you call the SocketAwaitable constructor,
> >     you're hooking up another event handler to the SAEA, and it's never
> >     being removed, so subsequent uses will cause the previous use's
> >     delegate to be invoked again, which is why you're getting the errors
> >     you're getting… a previous async method in which you used this SAEA is
> >     having its compiler-provided continuation delegate invoked again.  If
> >     you're going to pool something, you should be pooling instances of the
> >     SocketAwaitable, rather than the underlying SocketAsyncEventArgs… the
> >     design of the SocketAwaitable I posted expects that it logically owns
> >     the SocketAsyncEventArgs instance and that no one else will be using
> >     it.  By pooling the SocketAwaitable instead of the
> >     SocketAsyncEventArgs, you'll also avoid an extra allocation per usage.
> >     Good luck.

Comment: If you have a blocking message from Stack Overflow, then select all your message (ctrl-a or cmd-a), use the editor button with two braces {} to indent everything as a giant piece of code, post your message, ping me or someone else willing to help and we'll format it correctly for you.

Comment: Possibly related: [Unable to post question despite having fully properly formatted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376188/unable-to-post-question-despite-having-fully-properly-formatted-code#comment644028_376188)

Comment: While we don't know what is the guilty regex, I believe there is a threshold of reputation (like 100 or 2000) under which the filter kicks in.