# Why has my "good" edit, that fixed a significant number of issues, been rejected?

Tags: support, status-completed, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Today, I went to check my [all actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17201766/human%c3%a8?tab=activity&sort=all) tab to see what I did so far. I saw that [one of my edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30133315) got rejected.

As far as I see, the reason for rejecting my edit is "The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing."

Obviously, I fixed some stuff, so "The edit does not improve the quality of the post." doesn't fit here. As well as I didn't make the post more *confusing*. I think the changes I made were "unnecessary" or at least the post will survive without them, but if I can do something good, why don't I do it? :-)

Let me explain everything.

1. I've changed the "inputPhotoLocation" to highlight it as code, and well, "inputPhotoLocation" *is* code. `inputPhotoLocation` is a prop which is arguments passed into React components. So, clearly, it's code. Am I wrong?
2. I've changed "`./assets/GroupImages/football.jpg`" to highlight it as code. I did this because [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401464/17201766) says "When in doubt, prefer code formatting for technical content such as **file paths**, tracebacks, or logs.", "`./assets/GroupImages/football.jpg`" is a file path. Am I wrong?
3. I've removed "Thanks!" because [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/17201766) which says that "Thanks" and "Hope this helps" aren't useful. I've removed it. Am I wrong?
4. Fixed some grammar mistakes. I changed "cant" to "can't", and I added a question mark to the end of the title because it's a question.

I fixed some issues. Maybe I did something wrong? We're all humans, and we break stuff (usually). I'm posting this meta post in order to learn what I did wrong, and hopefully, I won't try to repeat it again.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly good edit to me, I would have accepted it.

Comment: Names of variables are only code if they are code. There are cases where formatting an isolated variable name is helpful, but mostly it just makes the text hard to read, and it is often a style choice, and mere style change is not a reason to edit. Those code format edits added nothing. Anyway the collected changes are so minor for a reviewed edit the drain on reviewers is not worth the improvements. Make such edits when you are no longer reviewed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your edit was rejected by the author of the post. Unfortunately, you can't assume they know what they're doing when it comes to "best practices" on the site. After all, they are the ones who made the mistakes in the first place. (This is not meant as an insult—new users are often unfamiliar with our policies, and doubly unfamiliar with the idea that the site is collaboratively edited.)

Your edit seems reasonable to me. You are doing the right things in your edits, and your logic is sound.

I have now retroactively approved your edit, overriding the decision of the post owner (which I can do because I am a moderator and there have been no intervening edits since).

Comment: Sorry it's quite off-topic, but I have same issue (reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412137/10952503)) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30010342) edit. Can you help me? Should I bump my meta question?

Comment: @Elikill58 Sure, no problem. That's a valid edit, and I was still able to retroactively approve it, so I did. I think I remember looking at your Meta question, but it slipped off my radar before I could take any action.

Comment: Ok thanks <3 And I understand, there is lot of question so it's normal to don't act on all

Comment: One of my early suggested edits on the site fixed an extensive number of grammatical and readability issues on a high-rep contributors answer. The edit was approved in the review queue but rejected by the author, who then applied most of my changes under his own account. (If I recall, this later happened _again_ with the same contributor.) As an fledgling contributor, it left a lousy taste in my mouth regarding edits. Fortunately, it's since proved to be quite rare, and thus I don't mind taking time to make extensive grammatical edits to otherwise useful answers.

Comment: @Jeremy Expanding on this a bit… Both moderators and post owners have the retroactive ability to override a community decision on a suggested edit. So, in your case, the community of reviewers approved it, but the post owner override that approval with a rejection. In this case, the community reviewers rejected the edit, but I used my moderator privileges to override that rejection with an approval. In both cases (post owner and moderator), this retroactive override can only be done if there are no intervening edits. Anyway, sorry to hear about that; suggested edit reviewing is quite imperfect

Comment: The edit summary was "***Formatting;***" and was not representative. Perhaps address that in your answer?

Comment: Kinda does look they improved the formatting. It isn't the world's greatest edit summary, I'll admit, but it does not seem to be particularly problematic to me.  Certainly not a reason to reject the edit, and definitely not an issue identified by any reviewer.