# Improve options for pending suggested edit on closed questions

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, closed-questions

The `edit` option on a closed question stated there were 3 options:

1. Approve
2. Reject
3. Improve

but the buttons seem to only be:

1. Approve
2. Approve
3. Reject

Does my account not have the `improve` option or is the panel incorrect with the options?

[image: Screenshot of panel]

Edit option:[image: Editoption]

Comment: That would be "improve and  reopen" or "improve and leave closed" ? or both? Also would you be approving or rejecting the edit in this action?

Comment: @SurajRao Oh, so `Approve` is a typo and should be `Improve`? As currently stated I would I think was only Approving the edit, not going to the edit portal after to make improvements.

Comment: Are you talking about the discrepancy between the flavour text in the top left (*"Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit."*) and the options (approve, approve, reject?)

Comment: Wait, is this option from the Close Vote review?

Comment: @AndrewT. No, it's the new suggested edit queue options for closed posts

Comment: @AndrewT. no suggested edit review. Only the suggested edit happens on a closed quesstion

Comment: "Approve, reject, or improve this suggested edit."  is the general text for suggested edits where you can approve/reject/approve and edit/reject and edit. I suppose the text just didn't change for closed questions as there is a third re open option.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I don't see a way to improve the edit. The edit has an error message as code, I planned to change that but couldn't find option.

Comment: @user3783243 That text is indeed, just flavour text for the queue as a whole, not the individual task. You get the same text for deleted posts and tag edits, despite the only options there being approve/reject (for users without the ability to unilaterally edit tag wikis). There is no improve option for closed posts.

Comment: @both: Alright, then I guess my edit is not wrong then. Thanks.

Comment: *The edit has an error message as code…* [Using code formatting for error code is valid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286706/how-should-compiler-errors-linker-errors-and-logs-be-formatted), especially if the error was originally in a monospaced font.