# Can I ask a question to get some suggestions from experts?

Tags: support, feature-request

I would like to create a Ruby Gem myself and for which I wish to ask for **some better ideas (technical requirement)** since I'm a bare beginner in this case. Please let me know where I could ask for a help regarding this? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Simple google search: ["How to make a ruby gem?"](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) The guide there is very long and (its length) should demonstrate why your question wouldn't be a good fit for SO.

Comment: @royhowie: I'm not asking about 'how to create a ruby gem'. I'm asking for an idea. Please read my question..

Comment: Just asking for project ideas is a bit broad anywhere. But if you at least have a topic/domain preference, you can certainly ask on SO Chat, some reddit community, or perhaps even IRC, or [join a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881/how-to-find-opensource-projects-looking-for-help).

Comment: @mario: Thank you. That makes sense!

Comment: Please note that inline code spans (`like this`) aren't meant to be used for highlighting, only for code in sentences. See this Meta question for more information: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: Even though I did not get what I expected, I appreciate all your inputs / feedbacks and will try to gather it on my own! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No, this sort of question isn't suitable on Stack Overflow or anywhere else in the network.  If you start work on this and get stuck on something specific, feel free to ask, but it seems like what you're asking is entirely too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. See, I need some good ideas to start off. An idea which has never been implemented and could help a lot of others. Only experts can help me on it I think. right?

Comment: At best you're going to get subjective remarks as opposed to expert advice, which isn't what you want.