# Trend to format keywords / product names as inline code

Tags: discussion, edits

My question is somewhat related to "[When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/213685)". When reviewing I have noticed the trend to edits that only format regular keywords or product names as inline code, for example: "I have a `L2TP/IPSEC VPN` Server [...]" ([link to review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12163822)) or "[...] migrate to `jQuery`" ([link to review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12163881)).

I have always rejected those edits but I have the feeling that they increase, I often see them multiple times in one review batch. What is the community opinion on this? How can we deal with this trend?

Comment: If it's not code it shouldn't be highlighted...it doesn't add anything that bolding wouldn't do. I'd reject / re-edit.

Comment: I want to discuss what to do against this trend, the other question discusses the legitimate use of inline code. So I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: There's not a lot you can do AFAIK. You can't **force** people not to do it and you can only reject the edits. There doesn't seem to be an option to *punish* a bad acceptance because *opinions differ*.

Comment: If your question is, should we stop rejecting this *because* it seems an increasingly popular edit, then "no". That in itself is not a reason, as long as the consensus is this should not be done. (A valid point until those editors gain so much rep that they can influence "the" consensus.)

Comment: Well, that was not my question. I thought of maybe informing the editor about the correct use of inline-code when the edit only introduces inline-code formats. But never mind, I accepted the duplicate.

Comment: ... One additional action you can take, beyond rejecting (which only helps if 2 more reviewers agree - I see that was a problem here...) and rolling back, is to leave the editor a message. Post editors can be `@` pinged, although you must type in their name. (Ah so you asked right before I pressed Enter!)

Comment: @RadLexus that's a good idea.

Comment: .. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886388/javascript-syntax-to-jquery#comment61342222_36886388 for an example. You can delete the comment after a while if you feel like it, or, if you happen to come across the same user doing it again, use it as a reminder that you asked earlier.