# Code markup (on Stack Overflow) and screen readers

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, accessibility

I once read a post on meta (specifically for Stack Overflow) about text formatted as code is bad for screen-reader users as the screen readers read each character inside a code block individually. 
E.g. this would be a `pain` to read, as it would say out loud "P-A-I-N"

Is this how screen-readers deal with code blocks?

This question was prompted by an edit that I wanted to flag as "caused harm" and reference it with the meta post (that I can't find...)

Related post:
[When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: Also related: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel from that question this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301372/179876 is the closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: I thought so (I promoted that comment into a community wiki answer). But this doesn't prove/disprove the assertion that text in code blocks is spelled aloud, just that people *might* have configured their screen reader to do so.

Comment: yeah it's a "depends on custom config" which is a vague an answer as possible, not even claiming it is default behaviour so pretty weak as an argument. Could have sworn there was a more strongly worded discussion about screen readers and code blocks somewhere