# What's the problem with this question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I asked a simple and straightforward [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346737). It has four downvotes, but no comments to say why. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Related: *[When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)* and *[Code markup (on Stack Overflow) and screen readers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331933/code-markup-on-stack-overflow-and-screen-readers)*

Comment: Huh? My question has nothing to do with code formatting.

Comment: Related: [The meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Re *"code formatting"*: OK, I will leave it to someone else to be less subtle.

Comment: Related: *[What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)* (includes *"I was looking for a PHP PDF library that supported a specific feature"*) (see also [the linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/254393?lq=1)) and *[Is my enforcement of Stack Overflow's policy against recommendation questions proper?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268287/is-my-enforcement-of-stack-overflows-policy-against-recommendation-questions-pr)*

Comment: Still *very* unclear on how anything about "recommendation" questions is at all relevant here. And, in general, a laundry list of "related" questions isn't particularly helpful to anyone. Everyone has access to the search feature, so *finding* the questions isn't the issue. It's knowing what to look for. If you don't take a moment to explain the relevance and make the connection, you aren't really helping. Related: [Completely unrelated "related" things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424848)

Comment: FWIW, it might help if the question would summarise the relevant parts of the linked question. It is rather difficult to piece together what is being asked if one needs to cross-reference two posts written with different focus and one not being meant to fit the other.

Comment: @NewSites Re: Your statement that your question has nothing to do with code formatting: [Your first revision of the question used code formatting for non-code text](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76346737/1).

Comment: @cottontail usefulness, voting is done based on usefulness. A useful question does not need to be of help right that same day. My guess is that the voting on this particular question is more based on how interesting someone finds it though, it is a curiosity-driven question and that invites the human condition.

Answer (score 12):

Although I'm not sure why you would expect any comments to have been posted to the question, I haven't the slightest clue either why there <strike>are</strike> were two close votes cast on that question. Both are ludicrous and apparently indefensible for anyone who read the question. One is that it is asking for a recommendation of an off-site resource, which is obviously silly, because the question is not asking for any kind of recommendation. It very clearly asks what the difference is between two different items that appear in a list of object library references in a VBA programming context. The other close reason selected by a different person is that the question lacks debugging details, which is particularly concerning, given that the question *isn't a debugging question* and isn't asking for any help to debug anything, so it doesn't need to include any debugging details. Again, for anyone who has read the question, it is inexplicable why they would think that any information is missing.

When close reasons are this absurdly incorrect, you really have no choice but to ignore them.

As for the downvotes, you have no real way of knowing. All you (or I) can do is make assumptions. Maybe:

- Someone didn't like that you used a code block for something that isn't code (like the name of an item in a list)?
- Someone thinks the question lacked research effort? (I don't know about this one. The answer doesn't seem to be trivially searchable, but questions that appear "simple" do often get downvoted for this reason.)
- Someone <strike>hates VBA and thinks it isn't "real" programming</strike> thought the question was not interesting and/or useful to others?
- Someone read *only the title*, and thought you were asking a totally open-ended question about which object library you should use with Microsoft Access? (I think this is probably likely, but very unfortunate. I mean, come on, it's not like the question was incredibly longwinded. Anyway, I've edited it to make the title more specific, which is a good example to follow in the future.)

I don't know what to tell you, really. Best I can tell, the folks who cast votes on this question didn't read it. If I'm honest, it's not a fantastic question, and it's not particularly interesting. I wouldn't upvote it. But I don't see anything wrong with it, or any reason why it's unsuitable for Stack Overflow. It might even help someone else in the future who has the same question. It's certainly niche, but our mission is to cover the long tail of programming questions, so not every single one is going to be riveting.

Comment: I haven't participated in any of the voting, but the last question makes it dangerously close: *"When would I prefer to select one over the other?"*. Which is not that far from *"Should I choose to learn Python or PHP?"*. Two libraries have been preselected instead of being open, but for being open, it wouldn't even have been accepted [on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour): *"Good software recommendation requests have two components: a purpose (a task to accomplish, a user story) and some objective requirements (a minimum set of features)."*

Comment: Dangerously close to what? It's *completely* different from "Should I choose to learn Python or PHP?" I would be in favor of removing close-vote privileges from anyone who couldn't tell the difference between these two questions. It's not a recommendation question at all, in any interpretation of the term. (So the rules of a completely different site are irrelevant, just in case they weren't already.) The question is asking what the difference is between two specific things that are directly comparable.

Comment: [rev 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76346737/3) opens with a brief vague sentence presenting a link to some post followed by "My references list includes Blah Library but it also includes Blah Blah Library Which one should I use? What's the difference?" This is all what's there, there's nothing else. You can use your mod powers to reopen such stuff how you like but to me, this changes nothing and question reads just a blatant library recommendation

Comment: "What is the difference between these two specific, similar-looking things in my development environment?" is not a recommendation question. That this point is lost on so many people active on Meta honestly makes me very concerned about the sustainability of the close voting system. The reason we don't allow recommendation questions is because they invite spam. It's the same reason we don't allow other open-ended questions that can have an infinite number of possible answers. This ain't that. Not even remotely close.

Comment: Maybe the problem is lacking any familiarity with the subject matter. For example, not knowing how VBA works, not knowing what the References dialog that is mentioned in the question is, and therefore just triggering on key words in a short question. Well, I have a solution for that, too: don't vote to close questions where you lack any knowledge whatsoever and are unequipped to determine whether the question is suitable for Stack Overflow. "It smells/looks bad" is not a close-vote reason. You absolutely have to have a better argument than that.

Comment: the problem looks more like lack of effort in supplying readers with useful details. The very question discussed here makes a good example: after asker added proper description of their issue it no longer looks like a recommendation, no matter if one has subject knowledge or not

Comment: There are no useful or important details missing from that question, even in its original form, given that one has sufficient subject-matter expertise to know what they're talking about.

Answer (score -13):

I did not see the question until you asked and I thought in the absence of any feedback I could speculate.

On a cursory reading by someone not fully understanding the question, they could have through you were asking how to find these libraries. Perhaps explaining a bit better might have helped misreading perhaps...

Asking how to find libraries is considered off-topic and a possibly a closure reason they thought.

For clarification, I did not downvote, I just wanted to offer a view.

Comment: Could you explain more, please? I'm not asking how to find a library. I've found two libraries with similar names and I need to know which one to use. How is that not relevant to programming? I need to use the right library in order to write a program. And if this really is off-topic, then where is the right place to ask?

Comment: I don't think the question asks to find a library. They are asking about the difference between two different versions.