# Should you explain the software you're using when posting about it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I was looking at [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518714/conditional-statement-in-formrequest) which I edited being the good samaritan I am, but I had no clue what the library being used actually **did**.

And I'm sure that the community that doesn't understand the Framework being used would also, not understand this question, or the library being used, so; if using libraries, is it a good idea to explain what the library does instead of asking **Library x Method not working**?

Comment: That's not necessary. As long as the library is mentioned and/or tagged then it's trivial to look up an overview of its purpose. Plus those who ask/answer/search-and-end-up-at a question should already know about the library.

Comment: Also please [don't use code formatting for emphasis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/880772).

Comment: Which also goes for your suggested edits, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14799947). Contrary to your stock description, it does `not` make `it` easier `to` read.

Comment: I apologize @approxiblue and **can't link**, I don't look into meta questions too often so I didn't know this was a problem, I'm going through all my edits and trying to re-edit them removing the hints; again I apologize to the fullest extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, post itself should not explain what library used in the post does. Post either should contain enough information to identify library (tag, link to library home/documentation) or MCVE without using library code.

If library has associated tag and question tagged appropriately than there is definitely no need to add any additional explanations to the question.

If question does not specify library in tags or body of the post ("I'm using the library and ...") - comment that OP must add tag or link to library and possibly vote to close as "unclear"/"missing MCVE" depending on type of question. If information about library not needed to understand the question - edit it out/reorganize post to move additional context to the end of post.

If question specifies library name only and it is not easy to recognize/search for - ask for clarification comment or better yet MCVE without library. Sometimes people post questions presuming everyone is perfectly aware of random internal library of company they work for or just some random code found on internet. Feel free to vote as "unclear" or "missing MCVE".