# Why does pressing 'Enter' after entering a comment while reviewing new user's first posts cause the 'No Action Needed' button to be pressed?

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-post-review

Why is it that, when reviewing a user's "First Posts", that if you type in a comment for that post, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the comment does not get entered and instead the "No Action Needed" button is pressed?

The only reason I noticed this is because it happened at the same time as an audit  which made me wonder: how is providing a useful comment the wrong action?

So, I investigated, and sure enough, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes your comment to be lost and the "No Action Needed" button to be pressed instead.

Is this designed this way for a reason?

Comment: [Don't use backticks to format arbitrary words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995).

Comment: @Tom is there some sort of reference page that has all of control codes on it for stackoverflow? I know of a few of them from the **Help** box underneath the **Add Comment**  box, but it doesn't say anywhere what the proper uses for each of the formatting markdowns are.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting?